# iPhone - UILabel containing text with multiple fonts at the same time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I am looking for a way to use a UILabel (or something similar) to display something like this:

**Tom:** Some message.

It is like how it's done in for example the Facebook app to display the "what's on your mind?" messages. Does anyone have any suggestions how to approach this?

Comment: Why do you even need <strong>one</strong> UILabel, as far as I know you can make it a view and add as many UILabel's to it as you want

Comment: You can use the same tools that the facebook app uses: three20 Joe Hewitt, the developer behind the facebook app has open sourced much of his work. You can get it and many other goodies here: http://github.com/joehewitt/three20

Comment: You cant do this within a UILabel..
But my suggestion is that instead of using multiple UILabel just concentrate on NSAttributedString... Find UIControllers that draw NSAttribute String because UILabel,UITextView doesnot support NSAttributedString... [Controller for drawing NSAttributedString](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Ali-Cocoa-Classes)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use two UILabel IBOutlets, each with a different format (font/color/etc), as you desire..  Move the second one over the first based on where the first one's text ends.  You can get that via sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:

Alternatively, you can subclass UILabel, and draw the text yourself in drawRect. If you do it this way, just add an instance variable to tell you how much of the string to draw in one format, and draw the rest in another.

Update:  Please see @Akshay's response below.  As of iOS6 UILabel's can contain NSMutableAttributedString.  When I wrote this, this was not available.

Comment: Or, to be more complicated than is probably necessary, build your own HTML to represent the message and display it in a UIWebView.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping for a more elegant solution. But apparently I just have to do it manually. Thank you!

Comment: An alternative would be using layers (specifically CATextLayer) Check this thread **Bold & Non-Bold Text In A Single UILabel?** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel

Answer (score 103):

There is a way to set different / multiple fonts & other properties on Label using NSMutableAttributedString. Foll is my code:

```
 UIFont *arialFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:18.0];
 NSDictionary *arialDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: arialFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];    
 NSMutableAttributedString *aAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes: arialDict];

 UIFont *VerdanaFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:12.0];
 NSDictionary *verdanaDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:VerdanaFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
 NSMutableAttributedString *vAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString: newsDate attributes:verdanaDict];    
 [vAttrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:(NSMakeRange(0, 15))];

 [aAttrString appendAttributedString:vAttrString];


 lblText.attributedText = aAttrString;
```

Note that lblText is the UILabel, outlet as file owner.
One can keep on appending as many NSMutableAttributedString he wants..

Also Note that I've added verdana & arial font in my project & added a plist for the same.

Comment: Keep in mind that UILabel's attributedText is available since iOS 6.0!

Comment: The combination of `-initWithString:attributes:` and `-appendAttributedString:` works beautifully and makes this very easy! Thanks so much for pointing that out.

Comment: this is the solution that works for me. because I wanted the text to have the same size and text width should fit the parent container.

Comment: perfect answer all the remaining are just waste suggestions i dont know why they didnt accepted this as a correct answer +1 this is what i can give i cant give more than that

Comment: @ashokdy because this answer was written in 2013, after many iOS updates since the question was written in 2009.

Comment: on color change line in example, change static '15'  in range to vAttrString.length.  --> 'range:(NSMakeRange(0, vAttrString.length))];'

Answer (score 27):

Sorry for late answer. Below code works great for me.
I am posting this so that it can be helpful to someone.

```
    UIFont *font1 = [UIFont fontWithName:kMyriadProSemiBold size:15];
NSDictionary *arialDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: font1 forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *aAttrString1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My" attributes: arialDict];

UIFont *font2 = [UIFont fontWithName:kMyriadProRegular size:15];
NSDictionary *arialDict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: font2 forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *aAttrString2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Profile" attributes: arialDict2];


[aAttrString1 appendAttributedString:aAttrString2];
myProfileLabel.attributedText = aAttrString1;
```

[image]

Please notice that My is semibold and profile is regular. I have used MyRiad font. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Update: If you are iOS 6+, then use UILabel.attributedText -- otherwise....

I created this basic UIView subclass to support similar functionality.

The list of things it **doesn't** support is longer than what it does, but basically it allows you to manage a **single** line of UILabels and format each as you want.  This lets me interject text with a different color in the middle of the line, for instance, and avoid using the heavy-weight UIWebView.

I create these objects by placing a UIView object in my interface (using Interface Builder) and setting the type of the object in IB to MultipartLabel.  Then in the code I call updateNumberOfLabels and the various setText selectors as needed.

```
//  MultipartLabel.m
//  MultiLabelLabel
//
//  Created by Jason Miller on 10/7/09.
//  Copyright 2009 Jason Miller. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MultipartLabel.h"

@interface MultipartLabel (Private)
- (void)updateLayout;
@end

@implementation MultipartLabel

@synthesize containerView;
@synthesize labels;

-(void)updateNumberOfLabels:(int)numLabels;
{
 [containerView removeFromSuperview];
 self.containerView = nil;

 self.containerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
 [self addSubview:self.containerView];
 self.labels = [NSMutableArray array];

 while (numLabels-- > 0) {
  UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  [self.containerView addSubview:label];
  [self.labels addObject:label];
  [label release];
 }

 [self updateLayout];
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text forLabel:(int)labelNum;
{
 if( [self.labels count] > labelNum && labelNum >= 0 )
 {
  UILabel * thisLabel = [self.labels objectAtIndex:labelNum];
  thisLabel.text = text;
 }

 [self updateLayout];
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text andFont:(UIFont*)font forLabel:(int)labelNum;
{
 if( [self.labels count] > labelNum && labelNum >= 0 )
 {
  UILabel * thisLabel = [self.labels objectAtIndex:labelNum];
  thisLabel.text = text;
  thisLabel.font = font;
 }

 [self updateLayout];
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text andColor:(UIColor*)color forLabel:(int)labelNum;
{
 if( [self.labels count] > labelNum && labelNum >= 0 )
 {
  UILabel * thisLabel = [self.labels objectAtIndex:labelNum];
  thisLabel.text = text;
  thisLabel.textColor = color;
 }

 [self updateLayout];
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text andFont:(UIFont*)font andColor:(UIColor*)color forLabel:(int)labelNum;
{
 if( [self.labels count] > labelNum && labelNum >= 0 )
 {
  UILabel * thisLabel = [self.labels objectAtIndex:labelNum];
  thisLabel.text = text;
  thisLabel.font = font;
  thisLabel.textColor = color;
 }

 [self updateLayout];
}

- (void)updateLayout {

 int thisX = 0;

 // TODO when it is time to support different sized fonts, need to adjust each y value to line up baselines

 for (UILabel * thisLabel in self.labels) {
  CGSize size = [thisLabel.text sizeWithFont:thisLabel.font
         constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(9999, 9999)
          lineBreakMode:thisLabel.lineBreakMode];
  CGRect thisFrame = CGRectMake( thisX, 0, size.width, size.height );
  thisLabel.frame = thisFrame;

  thisX += size.width;
 }
}


- (void)dealloc {
 [labels release];
 labels = nil;

 [containerView release];
 containerView = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason i work with this routine in several apps and is great, even in iOS 7 works, just updated sizeWithFont that was deprecated.

Answer (score 17):

In swift 2.0 this can be done as follows

```
//Defining fonts of size and type
let firstfont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 17)!
let boldFont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 17)!
let thirdFont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic", size: 17)!

//Making dictionaries of fonts that will be passed as an attribute        

let firstDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: firstfont, forKey:  
NSFontAttributeName)
let boldDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: boldFont, forKey: 
NSFontAttributeName)
let thirdDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: thirdFont, forKey: 
NSFontAttributeName)

let firstText = "My name is "
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: firstText, 
attributes: firstDict as? [String : AnyObject])

let boldText  = "Rajan"
let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:boldText, 
attributes:boldDict as? [String : AnyObject])

let finalText = " iOS"
let finalAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: 
finalText, attributes: thirdDict as? [String : AnyObject])

attributedString.appendAttributedString(boldString)
attributedString.appendAttributedString(finalAttributedString)
myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Edit 
 Swift 3.0**

```
let firstfont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 17)!
let boldFont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 17)!
let thirdFont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic", size: 17)!

//Making dictionaries of fonts that will be passed as an attribute

let firstDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: firstfont, forKey:
        NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying)
let boldDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: boldFont, forKey:
        NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying)
let thirdDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: thirdFont, forKey:
        NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying)

let firstText = "My name is "
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: firstText,
                                                     attributes: firstDict as? [String : AnyObject])

let boldText  = "Rajan"
let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:boldText,
                                               attributes:boldDict as? [String : AnyObject])

let finalText = " iOS"
let finalAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string:
        finalText, attributes: thirdDict as? [String : AnyObject])

attributedString.append(boldString)
attributedString.append(finalAttributedString)
myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Edit 
 Swift 4.0**

```
let firstfont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 17)!
let boldFont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 17)!
let thirdFont:UIFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic", size: 17)!

//Making dictionaries of fonts that will be passed as an attribute

let firstDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: firstfont, forKey:
    NSAttributedString.Key.font as NSCopying)
let boldDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: boldFont, forKey:
    NSAttributedString.Key.font as NSCopying)
let thirdDict:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: thirdFont, forKey:
    NSAttributedString.Key.font as NSCopying)

let firstText = "My name is "
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: firstText,
                                                         attributes: firstDict as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])

let boldText  = "Rajan"
let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:boldText,
                                                   attributes:boldDict as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])

let finalText = " iOS"
let finalAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string:
    finalText, attributes: thirdDict as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])

attributedString.append(boldString)
attributedString.append(finalAttributedString)
myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

This will look like

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! Using this with FontAwesome.

Answer (score 7):

I updated MultipartLabel suggested by @Jason adding contentMode (text alignment) support.

#### MultipartLabel.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MultipartLabel : UIView {
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIView *containerView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *labels;
@property (nonatomic) UIViewContentMode contentMode;

- (void)updateNumberOfLabels:(int)numLabels;
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text forLabel:(int)labelNum;
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text andFont:(UIFont*)font forLabel:(int)labelNum;
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text andColor:(UIColor*)color forLabel:(int)labelNum;
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text andFont:(UIFont*)font andColor:(UIColor*)color forLabel:(int)labelNum;

@end
```

#### MultipartLabel.m

```
//  MultipartLabel.m
//  MultipartLabel
//
//  Created by Jason Miller on 10/7/09.
//  Updated by Laurynas Butkus, 2011
//  Copyright 2009 Jason Miller. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MultipartLabel.h"

@interface MultipartLabel (Private)
- (void)updateLayout;
@end

@implementation MultipartLabel

@synthesize containerView;
@synthesize labels;
@synthesize contentMode;

-(void)updateNumberOfLabels:(int)numLabels
{
    [containerView removeFromSuperview];
    self.containerView = nil;

    self.containerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
    [self addSubview:self.containerView];
    self.labels = [NSMutableArray array];

    while (numLabels-- > 0) {
        UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        label.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
        [self.containerView addSubview:label];
        [self.labels addObject:label];
        [label release];
    }

    [self updateLayout];
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text forLabel:(int)labelNum
{
    if( [self.labels count] > labelNum && labelNum >= 0 )
    {
        UILabel * thisLabel = [self.labels objectAtIndex:labelNum];
        thisLabel.text = text;
    }

    [self updateLayout];
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text andFont:(UIFont*)font forLabel:(int)labelNum
{
    if( [self.labels count] > labelNum && labelNum >= 0 )
    {
        UILabel * thisLabel = [self.labels objectAtIndex:labelNum];
        thisLabel.text = text;
        thisLabel.font = font;
    }

    [self updateLayout];
}

-(void)setText:(NSString *)text andColor:(UIColor*)color forLabel:(int)labelNum
{
    if( [self.labels count] > labelNum && labelNum >= 0 )
    {
        UILabel * thisLabel = [self.labels objectAtIndex:labelNum];
        thisLabel.text = text;
        thisLabel.textColor = color;
    }

    [self updateLayout];
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text andFont:(UIFont*)font andColor:(UIColor*)color forLabel:(int)labelNum
{
    if( [self.labels count] > labelNum && labelNum >= 0 )
    {
        UILabel * thisLabel = [self.labels objectAtIndex:labelNum];
        thisLabel.text = text;
        thisLabel.font = font;
        thisLabel.textColor = color;
    }

    [self updateLayout];
}

- (void)updateLayout {

    int thisX;
    int thisY;
    int totalWidth = 0;
    int offsetX = 0;

    int sizes[[self.labels count]][2];
    int i = 0;

    for (UILabel * thisLabel in self.labels) {
        CGSize size = [thisLabel.text sizeWithFont:thisLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(9999, 9999) 
                                     lineBreakMode:thisLabel.lineBreakMode];

        sizes[i][0] = size.width;
        sizes[i][1] = size.height;
        totalWidth+= size.width;

        i++;
    }

    i = 0;

    for (UILabel * thisLabel in self.labels) {
        // X
        switch (self.contentMode) {
            case UIViewContentModeRight:
            case UIViewContentModeBottomRight:
            case UIViewContentModeTopRight:
                thisX = self.frame.size.width - totalWidth + offsetX;
                break;

            case UIViewContentModeCenter:
                thisX = (self.frame.size.width - totalWidth) / 2 + offsetX;
                break;

            default:
                thisX = offsetX;
                break;
        }

        // Y
        switch (self.contentMode) {
            case UIViewContentModeBottom:
            case UIViewContentModeBottomLeft:
            case UIViewContentModeBottomRight:
                thisY = self.frame.size.height - sizes[i][1];
                break;

            case UIViewContentModeCenter:
                thisY = (self.frame.size.height - sizes[i][1]) / 2;
                break;

            default:
                thisY = 0;
                break;
        }

        thisLabel.frame = CGRectMake( thisX, thisY, sizes[i][0], sizes[i][1] );

        offsetX += sizes[i][0];

        i++;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [labels release];
    labels = nil;

    [containerView release];
    containerView = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CoreText API it will be much faster.

Here are few [examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW1)

Basically the things you will have to do are:
1: Create UIView subclass
2: In the drawRect: method add the text drawing logic.

The text drawing logic:
 - You will need to know the range of the "name"
so if **Tom**: Some message. is your string you will have to apply different font for range (0, 3).

You can customize everything with CoreText :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi OHAttributelabel is good way for this.You can refer sample code with below link
https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel
Import OHAttribute framwork from it and you can set your label as below

```
 OHAttributedLabel *lblText;
 lblText = [[OHAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,19)];
 lblText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lblText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BoschSans-Regular" size:10];
    NSString *strText=@"Tom: Some message.";
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString: strText];
    NSRange rangeOfSubstring = [strVersion rangeOfString:@“Tom:];
    if (rangeOfSubstring.location != NSNotFound) {
        [attrStr setFontName:@"BoschSans-BOLD" size:10.0 range:rangeOfSubstring];
    }
    else {
    }

    lblText.attributedText = attrStr;
    [self.View addSubview: lblText];
```

Answer (score -5):

One option would be to use a UIWebView instead of UILabel.

An example:
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/display-rich-text-using-a-uiwebview

Answer (score -6):

it's quite easy to build you own HTML code =>

```
UIWebView *titleAd = [UIWebView alloc] init...;

NSString *cssString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".title {font-family: HelveticaNeue; text-decoration: bold; font-size: %fpt; color: #4083a9;} .author {font-family: HelveticaNeue; text-decoration: bold; font-size: %fpt; color: #3e4545;}",__FONTSIZE_29__, __FONTSIZE_21__];

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <head>     <style type=\"text/css\"> %@ </style> </head> <body>     <p>     <span class=\"title\"> %@ </span>     <span class=\"author\"> proposé par %@ </span>     </p> </body> </html>", cssString, [table title], [table nameOwner]];  

[titleAd loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: UIWebViews have a tremendous amount of overhead. This method is typically not recommended.