# iPhone colorize UILabel substrings

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I’m parsing a twitter rss feed, and I just need to show tweets, so I don't need MGTwitterEngine.
I have already set it up so I can see the complete tweet, the only thing I want it to colorize hashtags and urls.

So I would need to slice up the string in different substrings, colorize the hashtags and urls and glue it together in various UILabels

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?
In short I need some parts of a string colored differently than others.

Answer (score 0):

This question should answer your question: [iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time)

> Use two UILabel IBOutlets, each with a
>   different format (font/color/etc), as
>   you desire.. Move the second one over
>   the first based on where the first
>   one's text ends. You can get that via
>   sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
>
> Alternatively, you can subclass
>   UILabel, and draw the text yourself in
>   drawRect. If you do it this way, just
>   add an instance variable to tell you
>   how much of the string to draw in one
>   format, and draw the rest in another.