# How can you bold just one word in a UILabel?

Tags: iphone

It's easy to display a single label with entirely the same text but what happens when you want to display one word in bold?

Example:

All your bases **are** belong to us.

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UILabel` itself cannot draw a label with different attributes/fonts within the text. But Core Text can. You can create a subclass of `UILabel` that wraps an attributed string and uses Core Text to draw it. You can handle the drawing as in [this sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW18) from the Core Text programming guide:

```
// Build up your attributed string, then...
CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);

// Set text position and draw the line into the graphics context
CGContextSetTextPosition(context, 10.0, 10.0);
CTLineDraw(line, context);
CFRelease(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible. You could, however, subclass UILabel and include this functionality.

Another possibility would be using a UIWebView, but this requires using HTML tags and the loadHTML: method.

Answer (score 1):

As Evan Mulawski wrote, UILabel won't get you what you want. For that matter, neither will UITextField nor UITextView.

Another approach would be to subclass UIView and write a -drawRect: method that does what you want. You might look at

- CGContextShowTextAtPoint
- [NSString drawAtPoint:withFont:]
- [NSString sizeWithFont:]

If you won't be requiring a lot of line breaks and wrapping, then you could probably craft something fairly easily.

UIWebView would probably be faster but it seems like a lot of overhead for something as simple as a styled label.