# UILabel Text Color Change

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uilabel

[image]

output should be like this

[image]

```
UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,10,300,20)];
name.text =[Language localizedStringForKey:@"Name *"];
name.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
[name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.View addSubview:name];
```

How to change the color of one letter? I only need label text change.

Comment: NSAttributedString ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring

Comment: are you targeting iOS 6.0 and above?

Comment: @Senthil check my this answer which used for set multiple color to `UILable` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579209/two-colors-for-uilabel-text/13579318#13579318

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer :** [**NSAttributedString**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Check this Answer : [Answer for iOS5 and iOS6 also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586943/1603072).

**For Eg :**

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Name  *"];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(5,1)];
```

**Update :**

Make this change

```
[string addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName 
                value:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]
                range:NSMakeRange(5,1)];
```

Add following after `#import` line to your **.m file** :

```
#if (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE)
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
#else
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#endif
```

GoodLuck !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one.This will work on IOS6 or later version.

```
UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,10,300,20)];
name.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
[name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:name];

NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name *"]];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(5, 1)];
name.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: OP stated that he is developing for iOS 4.3 and onwards. attributedText property won't work for iOS 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSAttributedString` in default `UILabel` is available after iOS 6.0.

In order to support below iOS 6.0, you need to use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/). You can find usage and installation instructions on the readme file. Also note that it also uses `NSAttributedString`. So you can combine `TTTAttributedLabel` + `UILabel` to support both iOS 6+ and below.

Of course you can also create your own subclass of `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** 

(*Note: notation for attributed string key is changed in swift 4*)

Here is an extension for `NSMutableAttributedString`, that add/set color on string/text.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setColor(color: UIColor, forText stringValue: String) {
        let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: stringValue, options: .caseInsensitive)
        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
    }

}
```

Now, try above extension with `UILabel` and see result

```
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 280, height: 200)
let title = "Name"
let star = "*"
let stringValue = "\(title) \(star)"
label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
label.numberOfLines = 0
let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
attributedString.setColor(color: UIColor.red, forText: star)   // or use direct value for text "red"
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26)
label.attributedText = attributedString
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *newStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name *"]];
[newStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(5, 1)];
label.attributedText = newStr;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use NSAttributedString to be able to change attributes of single characters.