# How to set multiple color text in table view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a string  ... `Share Pictures` .I want to show the `Share` in different color.I used `NSMutableAttributedString` to change the color of that part of the string.But when I am setting the `cell.textLabel.text` using the following string it doesn't work.Any other way to do this?

This way it doesn't work.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string3 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Share pictures "];
[string3 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor orangeColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
NSString *tempStr3 = @"with your friends.";
NSString *finalString3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@" , string3, tempStr3];
[menuTextArray addObject:finalString3];
```

And in table view datasource method.

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [menuTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579209/two-colors-for-uilabel-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add only `NSMutableAttributedString` into your `menuTextArray`:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *yourString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Share pictures with your friends"];
[yourString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor orangeColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
[menuTextArray addObject:yourString];
```

then set `attributedText`

```
cell.textLabel.attributedText = [menuTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Okay.....but now I am getting excetion ......Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9daa5f0'

Comment: How are you adding objects in `menuTextArray` ? Make sure you are addin `NSMutableAttributedString` type object into your `menuTextArray` array, as I mentioned in code.

Comment: I convert one string and add to array then convert another and again add to array ....[menuTextArray addObject:finalString3];

Comment: Please see my code, how I added `NSMutableAttributedString` type object in array.

Comment: I just added the exact solution.....but now I am getting this....*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: This is exception becuase your array does not contain any objects and you are trying to access object from an empty array. Please update your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43907/discussion-between-icodes-and-bhumeshwer-katre)

Answer (score 1):

Use `attributedText` in place of `text`

```
cell.textLabel.attributedText = [menuTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you.....

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *string3 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Share pictures with your friends"];
    [string3 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor orangeColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];
    [menuTextArray addObject:string3];
    [cell.textLabel setAttributedText:string3];
```