# How to use multiple font stylings on a single string inside a label?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have a string consisting of -

```
lblWithText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblWithText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    lblWithText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
    lblWithText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Blah1:blah-blah%d. Blah2:-%d%%", [currentCoupon.couponPrice intValue],[currentCoupon.couponDiscountPercent intValue]];
```

Please tell me how to do that would be "Blah2:-%d%%"" was Bolden?
thanks in advance

Comment: the last line of your code is incomplete, please complete it.

Comment: if you want to bold the font , just replace Helvetica with @"HelveticaBold" or @"Helvetica Bold" , either of these will work

Comment: Thank you,but I need that to be bold only  "Blah2:-%d%%", but not the full string .. And I do not understand how to do.

Comment: if you want a part of string to be bold , you will have to use two different labels or UIWebview.

Comment: add two labels instead of one

Comment: I am sure there is no alternative to this....

Comment: There is an alternative. You can opt to use NSAttributedString instead. Using two labels is not a good option

Comment: @Atif, you are right , i found some links see my answer

Comment: Yes... +1 for adding these links :)

Comment: "Problems with foo" is not a really useful/descriptive title, especially when "foo" is a randomly chosen variable name (!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just required `Helvetica` font name with Bold like

`lblWithText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0];`

Just An Example ..

```
UILable *lbl1 = [[UILable alloc]init];
lbl1.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,100,40);
lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbl1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lbl1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
lbl1.text = @"Stack";

UILable *lbl2 = [[UILable alloc]init];
lbl2.frame = CGRectMake(110,10,150,40);
lbl2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbl2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lbl2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0];
lbl2.text = @"OverFlow";

[self.view addSubview:lbl1];
[self.view addSubview:lbl2];
```

this is an example which through you get idea ..

**UPDATE:**

**Also See this Example with NSMutableAttributedString:**

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Blah1:blah-blah%d. Blah2:-%d%%", [currentCoupon.couponPrice intValue],[currentCoupon.couponDiscountPercent intValue]];
[str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,30)];/// Define Range here and also BackGround color which you want
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,30)];/// Define Range here and also TextColor color which you want
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20.0] range:NSMakeRange(20, 10)];
lblWithText.attributedText = str;
```

Comment: thanks,but it does the Bold full label .. and I only need this piece-"Blah2:-%d%%

Comment: Fo this just use two lables and set frame with both in sequence dude for example see i will edit answer

Comment: You can opt to use NSAttributedString instead. Using two labels is not a good option

Comment: @Atif yes dude right ...

Comment: @Atif hey , just see i update the answer with example ... :) Thanx

Comment: @user1934383 hey see the normal example and also Attributs example.. just implement size and color which you want and which you add in string dude.. hope this helpful to you... :)

Answer (score 6):

Probably this can help you

[Bold & Non-Bold Text In A Single UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3586871/1030951)

it has solution for iOS 6 and for iOS5 you will have to use a CATextLayer with an NSAttributedString

or you may refer to http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ohattributedlabel

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/

https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/

Answer (score 1):

For full bold you can try with this

```
[lblWithText setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.f]]
```

Also go to this link for various [fonts](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6000-list-uifonts-available.html)

As you said you want some part as bold some normal, then you can try attributedString, but not sure.

Or go to this [link](http://cocoaobjects.com/egotextview/) and [this](https://github.com/omnigroup).

Answer (score 1):

Use NSMutableAttributedString for this please follow this tutorail for NSMutableAttributedString

http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-use-nsattributedstring-in-ios-6.html