# UILabel with different fonts

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this string that I want to display in a label:

```
 NSString *criticsScore=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\%%",[dict objectForKey:@"critics_score"]];

 _criticRating.text=criticsScore;
```

I want to set a small font for `\%%` and a large font for `[dict objectForKey:@"critics_score"]];`
Is this possible?

Comment: i cant get clearly plz elaborate your question :)

Comment: For example 75%.i want 75 of font "system 32" and % of font "system 15"in one Label.

Comment: Check out this class which can help you http://past.is/NDe3

Answer (score 8):

You Need to use your own control for drawing an `NSAttributedString`, like [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Blah1:blah-blah%d. Blah2:-%d%%", [currentCoupon.couponPrice intValue],[currentCoupon.couponDiscountPercent intValue]];
[str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,30)];/// Define Range here and also BackGround color which you want
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,30)];/// Define Range here and also TextColor color which you want
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20.0] range:NSMakeRange(20, 10)];
lblWithText.attributedText = str;
```

Above Code I got From [How to use multiple font stylings on a single string inside a label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068962/how-to-use-multiple-font-stylings-on-a-single-string-inside-a-label)

Answer (score 0):

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring). It is about `NSAttributedString`s. I think that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do it with two UILabels. You would set the first label to be all of the text excpt the \%%, and get the size of that label using sizeWithFont: on the text that goes in that label. Then set the second label to start at the end of that label's frame.

So, it would look something like  this, changing the coordinates based on where you want the labels:

```
NSString *criticsScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"critics_score"]];
NSString *str2 = @"\%%";

UIFont *criticsFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
UIFont *font2 = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];

//Get the sizes of each text string based on their font sizes.
CGSize criticsSize = [criticsScore sizeWithFont:criticsFont];
CGSize size2 = [str2 sizeWithFont:font2];


int x = 0;
int y = 0;
//The first label will start at whatever x and y are.
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,criticsSize.width,criticsSize.height)];
[label1 setFont:criticsFont];
//Create a second label with the x starting at x+criticsSize.width;
//The y will start at y+criticsSize.height-size2.height, so that it will be aligned with the bottom.
//Change these to align it differently.
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+criticsSize.width,y+criticsSize.height-size2.height,size2.width,size2.height)];
[label2 setFont:font2];
[self.view addSubview:label1];
[self.view addSubview:label2];
```