# How do I efficiently render pseudo-HTML with MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, nsattributedstring, xamarin, richtext

I need to draw a label that has some words in bold, consists of several paragraphs with different paddings and may contain small inline images (e.g. icons and bullets) from resources.

I know I could use [`NSAttributedString`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586943/458193) for bold and italic but it doesn't support paragraph margins or line limiting, and I'd rather use HTML/CSS-like solution because I'm getting the styles from server. It also won't allow me to insert my custom images in text without resorting to wrapping them in custom fonts.

Finally, I **don't** want to use `UIWebView` for performance reasons.
What MonoTouch libraries or bindings can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was happy to find out Hulu engineers wrote an iOS library that does exactly that. It's called [**GSFancyText**](https://github.com/hulu/GrannySmith/wiki/GSFancyText).

[In their own words](http://tech.hulu.com/blog/2012/06/11/grannysmith-for-ios-open-source-text-formatting-voiceover-and-more/):

> Of course we considered other options such as directly using HTML in a `UIWebView` or using `NSAttributedString`. But we decided to make our own style/markup parsing and rich-text drawing system, because of the following advantages:
>
> - It’s faster and consumes less memory than `UIWebView`s.
> - We can reuse the styles and parsing results in many places.
> - We can easily modify the style or text of a small part of a paragraph.
> - We can potentially extend the system with more fancy features, like Quartz 2D features,    animations, gestures, etc.
> - It makes localization simple. For example, a phrase marked as bold might be at a different position in the sentence in Japanese. In this case we can use a single `NSLocalizableString` to represent a sentence with various styles.
> - It’s easy to extract the plain text, on which we can enable the VoiceOver support.

The library is awesome so we went with creating [MonoTouch bindings for it](https://github.com/stampsy/MonoTouch.GSFancyText).

## Example

First define the styles using a CSS-like string:

```
var stylesheet = @"
    .green { color: #00ff00; font-weight:bold }
    .gray { color: gray; font-weight:bold }
";

GSFancyText.ParseStyleAndSetGlobal (stylesheet);
```

Then create a `GSFancyText` object with a markup string:

```
var fancyText = new GSFancyText ("<span class=green>Hulu</span> <span class=gray>Plus</span>");
```

Then you can directly draw this in a customized view:

```
fancyText.drawInRect (rect);
```

Or create a GSFancyTextView object to display it

```
var fancyView = new GSFancyTextView (frame, fancyText);
```

You can find more examples in [GSFancyTextView documentation](https://github.com/hulu/GrannySmith/wiki/GSFancyText).

My favorite feature are lambda blocks which allow you to specify a delegate to be called to render a `<lambda id=yourhandler width=50 height=50>` pseudoelement.

This allows you to insert custom images or do advanced inline drawing yourself.