# how to bold particular word in label in iphone

Tags: iphone

What me actually doing:-

```
lbl1= [[UILabel alloc] init];
lbl1.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10,90, 40);
lbl1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
lbl1.text=@"Definitions"; 
lbl1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];

UILabel* finalLabel=[[UILabel alloc] init];
finalLabel.frame=CGRectMake(100, 10,90, 40);
finalLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:,The following terms shall have the described meaning:",lbl1];  
 finalLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
finalLabel.numberOfLines=2;

[self.view addSubview:lbl1];
[self.view addSubview:finalLabel];
```

Didn't get the proper result of final label

it print:- Definitions
UILABEL:0X68640;frame(10,10,90,40);text='Definition',CliptoBound=YES;Userintraction......

Comment: add this line finalLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The following terms shall have the described meaning:"];

Comment: check this  :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel

Comment: @Sudha that i know, if we want to add both the label in one line,

Answer (score 0):

You mean partially bold in a single UILabel. right?

You should check this [ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel)

Answer (score 0):

Check out with below urls:

[Custom Label 1](https://github.com/petrpavlik/PPLabel)

[Custom Label 2](https://github.com/rootd/AMAttributedHighlightLabel)

It will be helpful to you and your functionality can be achieved.

Cheers!