# Create UILabel with differently styled text in iOS 5.1, without using storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I would like to create a one lined `UILabel` with a simple formatting that would look like this:
[image]

Never mind the underlining - it's the Photoshop thing.

I basically have 2 parts of the text, the left one with one font family, size and color, and another one with another.
Adding 2 labels one after another would make things extremely problematic and complicated. Any ideas how would you combine the thing into one simple `UILabel`? thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I don't use Storyboards or XIB's and I'm building for iOS 5.1 and up

Comment: @AnoopVaidya can you explain why is it a duplicate? I'm looking for a pre iOS6 solution and I would like to find new ways of solving this problem, the question you a referring me to doesn't have an answer for me.

Comment: pre ios6 or post ios6

Comment: @AnoopVaidya the one that would work **before** iOS6, which is, _obviously_, pre iOS6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used both of the following in apps that run in iOS 5+.

- https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel
- https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run iOS 5.0 and up, you can use the wonderful [TTTAttributedLabel](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel&ei=Dtc0Uf7sEIyNrgex-IGgDA&usg=AFQjCNHczBjr4fveLTjywFZ6UncKqT-rdQ&sig2=0RgwB4M7-JZ_sL-v0Cr0ig&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bmk) by mattt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two `UILabel`s aligned with one another using autolayout, or you can use the [`attributedText`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText) property available in iOS6

Comment: I agree. Attributed Text seems to be what you are looking for. You can even style it in Interface Builder, simply set the Text property from Plain to Attributed.

Comment: Apparently it's not possible since I don't use Stroyboards or IB. I can't use iOS 6 as well

Comment: Why is setting `attributedText` in code since you don't use storyboard or IB?

Comment: @DanF maybe because it's not available in iOS 5, huh?

Comment: Then your only option is to either use HTML formatted text in a `UIWebView` or two `UILabels`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel

Comment: Thanks, @Nick, it's really what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attributedText` property to handle this.

NSMutableAttributedString* string = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"OneThing (AnotherThing)"];

//this sets the font for the whole string

[string setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetice-Neue"]}];

//write another font here for "OneThing"

[string setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetice-Neue"]} range:NSMakeRange(0, 7)];

myLabel.attributedText = string;