# How to change the color of a specific word in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I want to change the **color** of a particular word from a **sentence** in IOS 5. 
Let my string be `NSString str = @"Your password is abc";`
I want to change the color of password **'abc'**.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring

Comment: Is it support in IOS 5?

Comment: it is only available since iOS6

Comment: How can i do this in iOS5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IOS 6 you could change the font, textColor, and textAlignment for particular word through attributedText you could find the documentation for this here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

Same question is answered in stackoverflow the link of the question is as follows

[Bold & Non-Bold Text In A Single UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel)

Comment: Ok.. Let me try.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this thing, hope it will work for you.

For a string like **firstsecondthid**, you can do like this. With first written in RED, second in GREEN and third in BLUE.

**Example code:**

```cs
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"firstsecondthird"];  
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];  
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(5,6)];  
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(11,5)];
```

Comment: I used this code. But i am getting the error message, 'use of undeclared identifier NSForegroundColorAttributeName'. What will i do?

Comment: Replace this   
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];  

with  
  
[string addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                   value:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]  
                   range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];

Comment: How can we set this NSMutableAttributedString to a label. I am very sorry if my question is wrong. I am a beginner in IOS. I used the code myLabel.text = (NSString*)string; But i am getting crash.

Comment: Very simple Just do this

self.attributedLabel.attributedText = string;

Comment: Remember no question is a silly question when you are in learning phase. So what ever is in your mind ask, explore and reach to answers. Try to improve you google skills to. If my answers worked for you, don't forget to mark as answer or VOTE correct. Thanks

Comment: I am getting an error 'property attributedText not found the object of type UILabel '.

Comment: Is it support only in versions higher than IOS 5. I am using IOS 5.

Comment: This works for IOS 6+, which IOS you using btw ?

Comment: How can we do it in IOS 5?

Comment: for ios5 Use a CATextLayer see the link provided in the answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel

Comment: This link could be very useful, use OHAttributedLabel

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

Comment: Getting error when using OHAttributedLabel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RTLabel` just set attributed text in the `rtLBLObj.text` it will show you relevent output.Just download and drag `RTLabel.h` and `.m` file in your project. you can down it from [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel)

Comment: ya it is a good method. But how can i append the value of text field to the label using this method.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers have mentioned, you need to use an `NSAttributedString` to store formatted text.

However, native support in iOS for attributed strings in `UILabel`s was only introduced in iOS 6.

If you want to support iOS 5 and below, there are many libraries around for displaying an attributed string. I would recommend using [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).

Comment: Sorry, Iam not familiar with podfile. Is there any other method to solve this issue?

Comment: You don't have to use a podfile, you can simply add the `.h` and `.m` files to your project.