# Making text within a string different from other text in same string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm basically trying to manipulate the string to have the Game Review portion either bold or a different color from the variable passed in as it's basically passing it all as the same size/color. Anyway to manipulate this in the same line or? What are my options? I was thinking of just having a static label Game Review and a separate label to pass this in that's set a different color/font but is there an alternative?

Here is the code I'm basically trying to manipulate:

```
NSString *gName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Game Review: %@",[aVideoGame name]];

itemView.gameName.text = gName;
```

Basically wanting Game Review bold, while the info passed in [aVideoGame name] isn't.
Not sure what to do here, as I'm a n00b.

Comment: Are you looking for `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: Take a look at NSAttributedString, and this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSAttributedString` and add attributes to each section of the string (`addAttribute:value:range:`), then set the `attributedText` of the label.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you basically want an [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and it's mutable friend, [NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableAttributedString). Several APIs, such as [UILabel's attributedText](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText) can deal with it, but you can also easily [render it yourself](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688). Be sure to read the [Attributed String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html), even though it talks mostly about the Mac, almost all of it also applies to iOS.