# app crashes when fetching contact image from ABAddressBook

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, abaddressbook

MY app is crashing when i try to fetching contact image from ABAddressbook the crashing result is due to "Receive memory warning.."

Comment: Where is the code where you tried to solve this using [`NSAttributtedstring`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html), looks like a a code request to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bold & Non-Bold Text In A Single UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel)

Answer (score 2):

There is a readymade code available in Git.I have used this and this will resolve you problem.

Try this:

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

Answer (score 1):

you have to use CoreText FrameWork.
Maybe this [tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) can help you

Comment: Mirko thanks for your comments..but i need NSAttributtedstring instead of using CoreText FrameWork

Comment: ok the important is that you fix your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can not create this with simple `UILabel`

https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel best one, lightwaited.