# How to dynamically change font weight in UITextView in iOS Mono

Tags: c#, ios7, mono, xamarin

I have a question how to change font weight in UITextView in iOS Mono?
For example i have text= "My name Foo.I Like to eat. #eat I love cookie";
i want to change display  "#hashtag" to bold

My name Foo.I Like to eat. **#hashtag**  I love cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this by using attributed strings. Below iOS6 you have to use CATextLayer.

Follow this great post:
[Bold & Non-Bold Text In A Single UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel)