# How to make part of a string bold in iOS?

Tags: ios, string

I want to make some part of a text string bold.

Eg:  **This is to be bold.** This is normal string.

In Android, it can be easily achieved by using spannable strings. What is its equivalent in iOS?

Comment: Look for NSAttributedString

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it can be achieved with [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html):

```
NSString *yourString = @"This is to be bold. This is normal string.";
NSMutableAttributedString *yourAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];
NSString *boldString = @"This is to be bold";
NSRange boldRange = [yourString rangeOfString:boldString];
[yourAttributedString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] range:boldRange];
[yourLabel setAttributedText: yourAttributedString];
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift version:

```
@IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var theTextview: UITextView!

        let theString = "Please satisfy three of the following password conditions" as NSString
        let theAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: theString as String)

        let boldString = "three"
        let boldRange = theString.range(of: boldString)
        let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

        theAttributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: boldRange)
        theLabel.attributedText = theAttributedString
        theTextview.attributedText = theAttributedString
```

Comment: Cann this be achieved somehow while keeping the app accessible to Dynamic Text?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Refer [Apple docs about NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html).

I'd tried [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17743543/756941) code to get bold and normal font in an UILabel.