# How to make some part of the text label bold in iOS Objective C programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

[image]

I have tried like this

```
#define KPrivacyText @"Your privacy is very important to us. We are committed \nto earn  your trust by safeguarding your personal \ninformation. All the information you provide to us is \nsecurely maintained and is kept strictly confidential. We \ndo not, and will not provide any personal information to \nyour organisation without your consent.\n\nThe governing principles: \n\n\n\u2022\tInformation is kept strictly confidential and secure. \n\n\n\u2022\tInformation is only used for the purposes stated.\n\n\n\u2022\tInformation is only shared with your consent."

_privacyText.text = KPrivacyText;
```

And I want "The governing principles:" in bold. Is there something like `\n` but for bold?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Seems someone already solve this problem. Please, checkout it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27222746/4577546

Comment: Is there anything like \b or   <b> <\b> in iOS.

Comment: `NS(Mutable)AttributedString` is the way to do it. For the rest, how to define what is bold or not, you could use Markdown (there are some libs that do translate it), HTML (Apple can do it), or specify your own markers to know where to bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `NSMutableAttributedString`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _isPolicyAccepted = NO;
    //_privacyText.text = KPrivacyText;
    self.title = @"Privacy Policy";

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your privacy is very important to us. We are committed \nto earn  your trust by safeguarding your personal \ninformation. All the information you provide to us is \nsecurely maintained and is kept strictly confidential. We \ndo not, and will not provide any personal information to \nyour organisation without your consent.\n\nThe governing principles: \n\n\u2022\tInformation is kept strictly confidential and secure. \n\n\u2022\tInformation is only used for the purposes stated.\n\n\u2022\tInformation is only shared with your consent."];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f weight:UIFontWeightBold] range:NSMakeRange(318, 27)];
    
    _privacyText.attributedText=attributedString;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `NSAttributedText` to achieve that.

```
NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];
NSString *yourString = ...;
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(22, 4);

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute:kCTFontAttributeName 
                   value:boldFontName
                   range:boldedRange];

[attrString endEditing];
//draw attrString here...
```