# Use multiple font colors in a single label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, textcolor

Is there a way to use two, or even three font colors in a single label in iOS?

If the text "hello, how are you" were used as an example, the "hello," would be blue, and the "how are you" would be green?

Is this possible, it seems easier than creating multiple labels?

Comment: Try using attributed text property of the UILabel.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel

Comment: You want to add To range color in string

Answer (score 174, accepted):

[**Reference from here.**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-set-use-multiple-font-colors-in.html)

First of all initialize of you **NSString** and **NSMutableAttributedString** as below.

```
var myString:NSString = "I AM KIRIT MODI"
var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
```

In **ViewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:2,length:4))
    // set label Attribute
    labName.attributedText = myMutableString
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**MULTIPLE COLOR**

Add the line code below in your ViewDidLoad to get multiple colors in a string.

```
 myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location:10,length:5))
```

**Multiple color OUTPUT**

[image]

**Swift 4**

```
var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font :UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:2,length:4))
```

**Swift 5.0**

```
 var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font :UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
 myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:2,length:4))
```

Comment: can you add two range properties, if not, how do I get around that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, I'm getting a two users' names consecutively from API. I want to color the second name, so I don't know the length of the sentence. Is there any solution for this case? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 84):

For @Hems Moradiya

[image]

```
let attrs1 = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.greenColor()]

let attrs2 = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]

let attributedString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Drive", attributes:attrs1)

let attributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"safe", attributes:attrs2)

attributedString1.appendAttributedString(attributedString2)
self.lblText.attributedText = attributedString1
```

Swift 4

```
    let attrs1 = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.green]

    let attrs2 = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]

    let attributedString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Drive", attributes:attrs1)

    let attributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"safe", attributes:attrs2)

    attributedString1.append(attributedString2)
    self.lblText.attributedText = attributedString1
```

Swift 5

```
    let attrs1 = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.green]

    let attrs2 = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]

    let attributedString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Drive", attributes:attrs1)

    let attributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"safe", attributes:attrs2)

    attributedString1.append(attributedString2)
    self.lblText.attributedText = attributedString1
```

Answer (score 43):

**Swift 4**

By using following extension function, you can directly set a color attribute to an attributed string and apply the same on your label.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setColorForText(textForAttribute: String, withColor color: UIColor) {
        let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textForAttribute, options: .caseInsensitive)

        // Swift 4.2 and above
        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)

        // Swift 4.1 and below
        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
    }

}
```

Try above extension, using a label:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 100, width: 260, height: 50)
let stringValue = "stackoverflow"

let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
attributedString.setColorForText(textForAttribute: "stack", withColor: UIColor.black)
attributedString.setColorForText(textForAttribute: "over", withColor: UIColor.orange)
attributedString.setColorForText(textForAttribute: "flow", withColor: UIColor.red)
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)

label.attributedText = attributedString
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @Krunal How can this be modified to support multiple strings to change colors...? I have a long string with underneath headers having ------------, but the code above works fine but it colors only the first found one. Can this be modified to do all --------- strings to a certain color....? Thanks.

Comment: this will no gonna work for text like this: "flowstackoverflow" it will change the first flow only,but we need the last one, how to achive that?

Answer (score 22):

Here a solution for **Swift 5**

```
let label = UILabel()
let text = NSMutableAttributedString()
text.append(NSAttributedString(string: "stack", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]));
text.append(NSAttributedString(string: "overflow", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]))
label.attributedText = text
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

**Updated Answer for Swift 4**

You can easily use html inside attributedText property of the UILabel to easily do various text formatting.

```
 let htmlString = "<font color=\"red\">This is  </font> <font color=\"blue\"> some text!</font>"

    let encodedData = htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
    do {
        let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
        label.attributedText = attributedString

    } catch _ {
        print("Cannot create attributed String")
    }
```

[image]

**Updated Answer for Swift 2**

```
let htmlString = "<font color=\"red\">This is  </font> <font color=\"blue\"> some text!</font>"

let encodedData = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
do {
    let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
    label.attributedText = attributedString

} catch _ {
    print("Cannot create attributed String")
}
```

Comment: I got this error message: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSAttributedString' with an argument list of type '(data: NSData, options: [String : String], documentAttributes: _, error: _)'

Comment: there are changes in Swift 2. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

I liked it this way

```
let yourAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
    let yourOtherAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)]

    let partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is an example ", attributes: yourAttributes)
    let partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "for the combination of Attributed String!", attributes: yourOtherAttributes)

    let combination = NSMutableAttributedString()

    combination.append(partOne)
    combination.append(partTwo)
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple one.

Answer (score 7):

Used [rakeshbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27728514/2752041)'s answer to create an extension in Swift 2:

```
// StringExtension.swift
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension String {

    var attributedStringFromHtml: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch _ {
            print("Cannot create attributed String")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let htmlString = "<font color=\"red\">This is  </font> <font color=\"blue\"> some text!</font>"
label.attributedText = htmlString.attributedStringFromHtml
```

Or even for *one-liners*

```
label.attributedText = "<font color=\"red\">This is  </font> <font color=\"blue\"> some text!</font>".attributedStringFromHtml
```

The good thing about the extension is that you'll have `.attributedStringFromHtml` attribute for all `String`s throughout your whole application.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE for **SWIFT 5**

```
func setDiffColor(color: UIColor, range: NSRange) {
     let attText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!)
     attText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
     attributedText = attText
}
```

**SWIFT 3**

In my code , i create an extension

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension UILabel {
    func setDifferentColor(string: String, location: Int, length: Int){

        let attText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
        attText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blueApp, range: NSRange(location:location,length:length))
        attributedText = attText

    }
}
```

and this for use

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        titleLabel.setDifferentColor(string: titleLabel.text!, location: 5, length: 4)

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Make use of `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:2,length:4))
```

[image]

See more details here [swift-using-attributed-strings](http://makeapppie.com/2014/10/20/swift-swift-using-attributed-strings-in-swift/)

Answer (score 5):

## Swift 3.0

```
let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(
                            string: "your desired text",
                            attributes: [:])

myMutableString.addAttribute(
                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                            value: UIColor.blue,
                            range: NSRange(
                                location:6,
                                length:7))
```

[image: result:]

For more colors you can just keep adding attributes to the mutable string.
More examples [here](https://makeapppie.com/tag/swift-nsattributedstring-in-swift/).

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 UILabel Extension**

In my case, I needed to be able to set different colors/fonts within labels frequently so I made a UILabel extension using [Krunal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5638630/krunal)'s NSMutableAttributedString extension.

```
func highlightWords(phrases: [String], withColor: UIColor?, withFont: UIFont?) {

    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!)

    for phrase in phrases {

        if withColor != nil {
            attributedString.setColorForText(textForAttribute: phrase, withColor: withColor!)
        }
        if withFont != nil {
            attributedString.setFontForText(textForAttribute: phrase, withFont: withFont!)
        }

    }

    self.attributedText = attributedString

}
```

It can be used like this:

```
yourLabel.highlightWords(phrases: ["hello"], withColor: UIColor.blue, withFont: nil)
yourLabel.highlightWords(phrases: ["how are you"], withColor: UIColor.green, withFont: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cocoapod [Prestyler](https://github.com/kruil/Prestyler):

```
Prestyle.defineRule("*", Color.blue)
Prestyle.defineRule("_", Color.red)
label.attributedText = "*This text is blue*, _but this one is red_".prestyled()
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 example using the HTML version.

```
let encodedData = htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
            do {
                let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
                label.attributedText = attributedString
            } catch _ {
                print("Cannot create attributed String")
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which supports **Latest version of Swift** as on Mar 2017.

**Swift 3.0**

Here I have created a Helper class and method for the

```
public class Helper {

static func GetAttributedText(inputText:String, location:Int,length:Int) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: inputText, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Merriweather", size: 15.0)!])
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 0.401107, green: 0.352791, blue: 0.503067, alpha: 1.0) , range: NSRange(location:location,length:length))
       return attributedText
    }
}
```

In the Method Parameters,
inputText:String - your Text to be displayed in label
location:Int - where the style should be application, "0" as start of the string or some valid value as character position of the string
length:Int - From the location until how many characters this style is applicable.

Consuming in other method:

```
self.dateLabel?.attributedText = Helper.GetAttributedText(inputText: "Date : " + (self.myModel?.eventDate)!, location:0, length: 6)
```

Output:

[image]

Note: The UI Color can be defined color as `UIColor.red` or user defined colors as `UIColor(red: 0.401107, green: 0.352791, blue: 0.503067, alpha: 1.0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
func MultiStringColor(first:String,second:String) -> NSAttributedString
    {
        let MyString1 = [NSFontAttributeName : FontSet.MonsRegular(size: 14), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : FoodConstant.PUREBLACK]

        let MyString2 = [NSFontAttributeName : FontSet.MonsRegular(size: 14), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : FoodConstant.GREENCOLOR]

        let attributedString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:first, attributes:MyString1)

        let attributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:second, attributes:MyString2)

        MyString1.append(MyString2)

        return MyString1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for using this **NSForegroundColorAttributeName** in swift lower version you can get unresolved identifier issues change the above to **NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor**.

```
             swift lower version                swift latest version
```

i.e., **NSForegroundColorAttributeName** == **NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor**

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    var stringAlert = self.phoneNumber + "로\r로전송인증번호를입력해주세요"
    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringAlert, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle:paragraphStyle,  .font: UIFont(name: "NotoSansCJKkr-Regular", size: 14.0)])
    attributedString.setColorForText(textForAttribute: self.phoneNumber, withColor: UIColor.init(red: 1.0/255.0, green: 205/255.0, blue: 166/255.0, alpha: 1) )
    attributedString.setColorForText(textForAttribute: "로\r로전송인증번호를입력해주세요", withColor: UIColor.black)

    self.txtLabelText.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Result**
 
[image: Result]