# NSAttributedString issues in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, nsattributedstring

I'm getting issues with NSAtrributedString no matter which path I take and can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

With the code below I get: `Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(string: StringLiteralConvertible, attributes: $T6)'`

```
let cancelButtonTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "CANCEL", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: buttonFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
```

Any ideas where the issue lies?  I've tried in xcode 6.1 and 6.2.

Comment: can you please show the line you define the buttonFont variable?

Comment: see how to use NSAttributedString http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728466/use-multiple-font-colors-in-a-single-label-swift/27728516#27728516

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSFontAttributeName` should be set to a `UIFont` object.

```
let buttonFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)

let cancelButtonTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "CANCEL",
    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: buttonFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
```

or if you are using a specific font.

```
if let buttonFont = UIFont(name: "Your Font", size: 10) {

    let cancelButtonTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "CANCEL",
    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: buttonFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
}
```

because `UIFont(name:,size:)` constructor returns an `optional`, you need to unwrap it before using it in `NSAttributedString`

Comment: I was using a specific font:

`let buttonFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 25)`

So that fixed it.