# Swift UITextView with different formatting

Tags: swift, uitextview

Sorry for a basic question, but I'm not sure where to start. Is the following possible in Swift?

> In a *UITextView* (Not a label, as in the possible duplicate), different bits of text having different formatting: for instance, a line of large text in the same UITextView as a line of small text. Here is a mockup of what I mean:
> [image]

Is this possible in one UITextView?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use multiple font colors in a single label - Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728466/use-multiple-font-colors-in-a-single-label-swift)

Comment: @Thilo I don't think it's a duplicate: the question you referenced is about labels, not text views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at `NSAttributedString`. Here's an example of how you could use it:

```
    let largeTextString = "Here is some large, bold text"
    let smallTextString = "Here is some smaller text"

    let textString = "\n\(largeTextString)\n\n\(smallTextString)"
    let attrText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)

    let largeFont = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 50.0)!
    let smallFont = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30.0)!

    //  Convert textString to NSString because attrText.addAttribute takes an NSRange.
    let largeTextRange = (textString as NSString).range(of: largeTextString)
    let smallTextRange = (textString as NSString).range(of: smallTextString)

    attrText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: largeFont, range: largeTextRange)
    attrText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: smallFont, range: smallTextRange)

    textView.attributedText = attrText
```

The result:

[image]