# Is it possible to set a different colour for one character in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, uilabel

I've been working on a small project using Xcode. It uses a lot of labels, textfields, etc. I've finished with most of the layout, the constrains, and the forms, titles, etc. After which, the client announces that for all required fields, there should be a red asterisk next to the label.

Call me lazy, but I'd rather not go back to all of my forms, add in a lot of labels with asterisks on them, and re-do my auto-layout to accommodate the new labels.

So, is there a way to change the colour of a specific character (in this case, the asterisk) in a UILabel, while the rest of the text stays black?

Comment: Look at using attributed strings which you can set to the label. This allows you to set different colours, as well as font sizes, etc.

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString` does this for you. You can set different property for different range of string.

Comment: Is the effort you would like to achieve it with requires a) not to touch layout code by adding some `UILabel` next to existed `UILabel`s b) not to add asterisk manually to each string you assign to `.text` or `.attributedText` properties of `UILabel`? So, you just want some `UILabel`'s extension or `UILabel`'s subclass with red asterisk being added at the end of each `UILabel` you specify, don't you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `NSMutableAttributedString`.
You can set specific range of your string with different color, font, size, ...

E.g:

```
 var range = NSRange(location:2,length:1) // specific location. This means "range" handle 1 character at location 2

 attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalString, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
 // here you change the character to red color
 attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: range)
 label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Ref: [Use multiple font colors in a single label - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728466/use-multiple-font-colors-in-a-single-label-swift)

You can change a lot of attribute of String. 
Ref from apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html

Comment: This code is copied straight from the top of the answer you're linking to, and in its current form, adds nothing that a comment linked to this thread couldn't have achieved, rather than an answer of your own. Hence, I downvoted this. If you however refine the answer and show the OP how to use this w.r.t. `UILabel`:s (which is his question), I will reverse my down-vote. [See this meta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer), especially the part in the answer regarding _effort_ by an answerer.

Comment: @dfri Thank you very much. It's really bad. Sorry. I updated my answer for more sense :). I was busy at that time. So I just want the OP see the answer at the link I found. Thank you. :)

Comment: You're welcome, and that's better, reversed my vote!

Answer (score 9):

```
let text = "Sample text *"
let range = (text as NSString).rangeOfString("*")
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor() , range: range)

    //Apply to the label
    myLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: Taken from an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207373/changing-specific-texts-color-using-nsmutableattributedstring-in-swift) without attribution.

Comment: Thank you Its Working Perfectly.

Comment: if there is more then one (*) and I want change color of all (*) then what is do.

Answer (score 4):

`UILabel` have an `.attributedText` property of type `NSAttributedString`.

> **Declaration**
>
> @NSCopying var attributedText: NSAttributedString?

You let your asterix `*` have a single `.redColor()` attribute (`NSForegroundColorAttributeName`), whereas the rest of the new label simply uses the same text as before, however also contained in an `NSAttributedTextString`.

An example follows below using a function to repeatedly update your existing labels to attributed strings prefixed with a red `*`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myFirstLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mySecondLabel: UILabel!

    let myPrefixCharacter = "*"
    let myPrefixColor = UIColor.redColor()    

    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ...

        /* update labels to attributed strings */
        updateLabelToAttributedString(myFirstLabel)
        updateLabelToAttributedString(mySecondLabel)
        // ...

    }

    func updateLabelToAttributedString(label: UILabel) {

        /* original label text as NSAttributedString, prefixed with " " */
        let attr = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: myPrefixColor ]
        let myNewLabelText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myPrefixCharacter, attributes: attr)
        let myOrigLabelText = NSAttributedString(string: " " + (label.text ?? ""))

        /* set new label text as attributed string */
        myNewLabelText.appendAttributedString(myOrigLabelText)
        label.attributedText = myNewLabelText
    }

    // ...

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4** 

(*Note: notation for attributed string key is changed in swift 4*)

Here is an extension for `NSMutableAttributedString`, that add/set color on string/text.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setColor(color: UIColor, forText stringValue: String) {
        let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: stringValue, options: .caseInsensitive)
        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
    }

}
```

Now, try above extension with `UILabel` and see result

```
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 280, height: 200)
let red = "red"
let blue = "blue"
let green = "green"
let stringValue = "\(red)\n\(blue)\n&\n\(green)"
label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
label.numberOfLines = 0
let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
attributedString.setColor(color: UIColor.red, forText: red)   // or use direct value for text "red"
attributedString.setColor(color: UIColor.blue, forText: blue)   // or use direct value for text "blue"
attributedString.setColor(color: UIColor.green, forText: green)   // or use direct value for text "green"
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26)
label.attributedText = attributedString
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func updateAttributedStringWithCharacter(title : String, uilabel: UILabel) {
    let text = title + "*"
    let range = (text as NSString).range(of: "*")
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red , range: range)
    uilabel.attributedText = attributedString }
```

Comment: updateAttributedStringWithCharacter(title: lbl_name.text!, uilabel: lbl_name) 
Use this function to show Star(*) after the label

Note -: User above function in viewDidLoad() to get effect.
Taken ref from @tuledev's answer

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but i want to share my approach (which is based on the answer from dfri) i just made it a function for convenience.

```
func lastCharOnColor(label: UILabel, color: UIColor, length: Int) {

    //First we get the text.
    let string = label.text

    //Get number of characters on string and based on that get last character index.
    let characterCounter    = string?.characters.count
    let lastCharacterIndex  = characterCounter!-1

    //Set Range
    let range = NSRange(location: lastCharacterIndex, length: length)
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string!, attributes: nil)

    //Set label
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: range)
    label.attributedText = attributedString

}
```

I use this function to just set the last character from a label to a certain color like this:

```
        lastCharOnColor(label: self.labelname, color: UIColor.red, length: 1)
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension for simply making mandatory labels by appending a red *

Swift 5

```
extension UILabel {
func makeTextMandatory() {
    let text = self.text ?? "" + " *"
    let range = (text as NSString).range(of: " *")
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red , range: range)
    self.attributedText = attributedString
  }
}
```

Usage :

```
dobLabel.makeTextMandatory()
```