# How can I highlight portion of text inside a UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Let say I have a text like this "By signing up I agree to the Terms of use and Privacy policy of Rue.Du.8  " inside a `UITextField` , I want to make the whole color Grey except "Terms of use" as white color . Is it possible to achieve into a `UITextField`?

[image]

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728466/use-multiple-font-colors-in-a-single-label-swift

Comment: I would use a text view so you can make the terms of use and privacy links work. Text fields don't have that functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the `attributedPlaceholder` property, first create an `AttributedString`, like this.

```
var str = "By signing up I agree to the Terms of use and Privacy policy of Rue.Du.8"
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.grayColor(), range: (str as NSString).rangeOfString(str))
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor(), range: (str as NSString).rangeOfString("Terms of use"))
self.textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString
```

Comment: sorry :p , new user here :(

Comment: Then its Ok :), Welcome on `SO` :)