# How to add color to a specific text in Xcode using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am appending a text on the end of a string that I have received by making the API Call in Xcode. Now, I want to add colour and make only the text "Tap to Read More" bold. Any suggestions on how can I achieve that? Would appreciate your help:)

```
self.content[i] = recievedData.title! + "\nTap to Read More "

let str = "Tap to Read More"
    
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
    ]

    let attributedQuote = NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attributes)
```

Comment: You are looking for `NSAttributeString`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use multiple font colors in a single label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728466/use-multiple-font-colors-in-a-single-label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `NSAttributedString`.

Example:

```swift
let str = "Tap to Read More"

// Create your attributed string
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]
let attributedStr = NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attributes)

// Example for a UILabel
let lbl = UILabel()
lbl.attributedText = attributedStr
```

---

Doc on `NSAttributedString`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is giving me the following error:- Value of type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'addAttribute'