# UITextView with custom font not working when text set to "attributed"

Tags: xcode, swift, nsattributedstring, custom-font

I have a `UITextView` with some text that came from a .rtf (pasted directly onto Xcode)

The context contain only one custom font (Futura Book BT 11.0)

If I set the "text(attributed)" property to "plain"= The custom font appear properly from the storyboard and from the app

If I set the "text" property to "attributed"=. The custom font appear properly from the storyboard BUT not from the app.

As my goal was to have a text with multiple font working, how to have the attributed property to work with custom fonts? (Swift)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

> The custom font appear properly from the storyboard BUT not from the app.

Does the app not show the font at all, or does it restore to system font? If it is reverting to Helvetica, it looks like this may be a known bug in iOS 8.1
 http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5117089870249984

**Possible Solution:**
Did you test it on the simulator and a device? It could be that it just doesn't work on the simulator, which means you could fix it by installing the font on your system.

Comment: It's reverting to Helvetica.

Comment: try installing it on your Mac with Font Book?

Comment: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5117089870249984 = Got-It.  Looks like it was exactly this bug!

Comment: Adding the font to your Mac's Font Book app doesn't fix the problem. It just looks like it fixes the problem. The solution is to, as other answers show, add the attributed string at run time. Works like a champ. Better yet, set your font in IB to something that should work like Helvetica. Then do this: `[attrib enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attrib.length) options:0
                            usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop)` and remove the font and add your custom font. Be sure to check bold, italic, etc type.

Answer (score 8):

I have faced the same problem when I used multiple custom fonts in attributed UILabel. Storyboard shows correct result but device does not!!

What I have find out that if the font size is different of text with different custom fonts. It works fine!!

So for now I use font size with minor difference. Like if one is 14 I used 14.01 for the other. Its not possible inside storyboard so I opened storyboard as source code and manually set font size like:

```
<attributedString key="attributedTitle">    
  <fragment content="Do not have account? ">
      <attributes>
        <color key="NSColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
        <font key="NSFont" size="14" name="Roboto-Light"/>
        <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="center" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural" tighteningFactorForTruncation="0.0"/>
      </attributes>
    </fragment>
    <fragment content="Login">
      <attributes>
        <color key="NSColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
        <font key="NSFont" size="14.01" name="Roboto-Bold"/>
        <paragraphStyle key="NSParagraphStyle" alignment="center" lineBreakMode="wordWrapping" baseWritingDirection="natural" tighteningFactorForTruncation="0.0"/>
      </attributes>
    </fragment>
<attributedString key="attributedTitle">
```

But still I am unable to find why it happens!

Comment: try changing the text alignment. in my case it worked when i changed it to left instead of justified

Comment: On Xcode 10 worked for me adding .01 to text font size.. :(

Answer (score 4):

What I do:

```
private var _mutableString: NSMutableAttributedString!

if !isTitle {
    var titleFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: StyleGlobals.TitleFontName, size: StyleGlobals.TitleFontSize)!
    self._mutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: titleFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(self._mutableString.string)))
    self._mutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: StyleGlobals.FontColor, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(self._mutableString.string)))
}

self.Label.attributedText = self._mutableString
```

This applies both a new font color as well as the font itself. I have a certain UILabel that is has to be able to contain different fonts. It can either be a Title or a subtitle. Hence I had to apply the font when I had determined what the Label is going to contain.

Comment: I will try this.
1- Doing this, can i set the .text via the storyboard?
2- If the UITextview contains multiples custom font, how can I manage it using your code?

Thanks again!

Comment: I personally don't know I you're able to do this via the storyboard. However if you want to have a string with multiple fonts. I think you have to split your string into multiple mutable strings and later append them together with: appendAttributedString. Atleast that seems like the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Still no suggestion to get it work using the storyboard?

Comment: I'm assuming the following doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25892126/1235505. Regarding to my comment before your previous one. appendAttributedString isn't required. You could just apply a font to a specific range. Forgive me for not realizing sooner. Maybe better performant than appendAttributedString.

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure that "Futura Book BT" is correctly added as a custom font in your app?

Comment: Yes.  I'm absolutely sure. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that I didn't have the font installed on my system, so I did it with Font Book.
Then, the font appeared on the list in attributed text labels.

**EDIT:** Now I had some problems for displaying my current text and did this (I'm using a UILabel, not tested on UITextView):

My solution is to create an attributed string from html (saw this extension somewhere here in SO):

```
extension String {
    var html2AttStr: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [
                                            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            //print(error.code)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And then what I do is something like:

```
let htmlStyle = "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><style> body { font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Light'; font-size: 18px; text-align: center; } b {font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Light'; }</style>"
let myString = "<font size=\"+2\">Slightly bigger font</font><br><br>Some message with normal text <b>a bold text</b> and some more text"
var attributedString = htmlStyle
attributedString.appendContentsOf(myString)
informationLabel.attributedText = attributedString.html2AttStr
```

One of the advantages of this is that I can now put some '%s' text inside the string for parsing with a word/number/etc. and It's easier to translate and parse. With formatted text I had to make a bunch of code for finding text, applying format without touching anything around. This works pretty well for me :)

Comment: That will work to get the font to show up in IB. But when you actually run your app, the font is not used.

Comment: Yup, I now have got to that point. Once was working, and now it seems it's not working... hurray! :D
I'll edit my answer with my fix.

Answer (score 1):

Please call all your code in **viewDidLayoutSubviews** method!
Than works. 
I have many problems when chanhing font size, style i viewDidLoad or viewWillApperar methods.

So just move your code in **viewDidLayoutSubviews** method. You can use flag to change fonts only once since this method can be called many times :]

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this extension**

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func createAttributedString(word : NSArray, attributeCustomizeFont:UIFont, defaultFont : UIFont, defaultColor : UIColor, allowSpecing : Bool , allowUnderLine : Bool = false) -> NSAttributedString {

        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: defaultFont, range: (self.string as NSString).range(of: self.string))
        if allowSpecing {
            self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: NSNumber(value: 5), range: (self.string as NSString).range(of: self.string))
        }else {
            self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: NSNumber(value: 0), range: (self.string as NSString).range(of: self.string))
        }

        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: defaultColor, range: (self.string as NSString).range(of: self.string))

        for i in 0..<word.count {
            self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: attributeCustomizeFont, range: (self.string as NSString).range(of: word.object(at: i) as! String))

        }
        if allowUnderLine {
            self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: (self.string as NSString).range(of: self.string))
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

**How to use extension**

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Test for set custom font")
        attributedString = attributedString.createAttributedString(word: ["custom font"], attributeCustomizeFont: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18)! , defaultFont: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15)!, defaultColor: UIColor.black, allowSpecing: false) as! NSMutableAttributedString
```

So the whole string font set 'Helvetica' with size 18 and for '*custom font'* text set 'Arial' font with size 15.

Answer (score 0):

Making UITextview "selectable" from storyboard will work.

Answer (score 0):

✅FIXED :

Fixed by subclassing my `UITextView` as [KMPlaceholderTextView](https://github.com/MoZhouqi/KMPlaceholderTextView) which is also useful for adding a placeholder to text view and can be used from Interface Builder as same as `UITextField`.

Now I can use custom fonts successfully and add placeholder text.

Answer (score -1):

There is a workaround. Just double click on font file(in Finder) and install it in to system.

Answer (score -1):

I used the different font sizes but still facing the issues. Then i changed the text alignment to left instead of justified. Then it worked fine.