# Multiple custom fonts in UILabel in Xcode 9 storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

Whenever I use multiple custom fonts in an attributed text of an UILabel in the storyboard it won't work on any device or in the simulator although everything is displayed correctly in the storyboard view within Xcode.

I still don't know why that happens but I found a workaround here which works for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47284854

Comment: First read this how to add custom font in Xcode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: I know how to include fonts. It works fine when I set the attributed text with the custom fonts programmatically it just doesn't work on the device when I set them in the storyboard. Even in the storyboard view the custom fonts are being displayed the right way.

Comment: Make use your are using **PostScript name**  like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006772/custom-font-not-working-programetically-in-swift#28843547

Comment: My fonts are included the right way with their corresponding postscript names. I can use multiple custom fonts in a UILabel when I do it programmatically. This is just a storyboard issue.