# iOS / Swift: Is it possible to selectively change the font in parts of a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Is it possible to selectively change the font in parts of a **UITextView**?

I have got a **UITextView** and would like to selectively change the font size and style for parts of it. For example

> **Lorem ipsum dolor** sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing
>   pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor **incididunt** ut labore et dolore magna
>   aliqua. Ut enim ad **minim** veniam

Comment: Using `NSAttributedString` you can achieve this.

Comment: Absolutely it is possible. Although on a word of caution from my experience, it's best to make this attributed string a generic method that can be called anywhere. Apple has been known to modify the syntax from Swift version upgrade.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bold & Non-Bold Text In A Single UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSAttributedString` to give attributes on string using addAttribute method.

```
 let string = "Bold Italics Roman"
 let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Open Sans", size: 18.0)!]
 let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)

 let sampleString = string as NSString
 let range  = sampleString.range(of: "Italics")
 attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Italic", size: 18.0)!, range: range)

 textView.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this  using NSString and attribute with the rangeofString: method

```
let longString = "Lorem ipsum dolor. VeryLongWord ipsum foobar"
let longestWord = "VeryLongWord"

let longestWordRange = (longString as NSString).rangeOfString(longestWord)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: longString, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)])

attributedString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()], range: longestWordRange)


label.attributedText = attributedString
```