# IOS swift is there a way to make a specific portion of text bold

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a `UITableview` that gets data from the database and I display it in a `UILabel`. I want to make a portion of the text that says " ... Read Less" to be bold while leaving the rest of the text alone. The code below simply checks if the post has more than 120 characters if so then I append " ... Read Less " that statement appended I would like to make bold. Right now I have my entire post bold instead of just the appended string any suggestions would be great

```
func HomeProfilePlaceTVC(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeTVC

    cell.post.tag = indexPath.row 

    if streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row].count > 120 {
            cell.post.text = String(streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row]).appending(" ... Read Less")
            cell.post.font =  UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15.0)
        }

        else {
             cell.post.text = streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row]
        }
    return cell

}
```

Comment: Did you try using attributed string . Use the range of the string which you wanna be bold . This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586943/4489420

Comment: Are you want to bold this text **" ... Read Less"** by count dynamically of prefix text?

Comment: is the below answer helpful for you? Did it solved your query? @user1591668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension like this.

```
extension String {
    func attributedString(with style: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil,
                          and highlightedText: String,
                          with highlightedTextStyle: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil) -> NSAttributedString {

        let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self, attributes: style)
        let highlightedTextRange: NSRange = (self as NSString).range(of: highlightedText as String)
        formattedString.setAttributes(highlightedTextStyle, range: highlightedTextRange)
        return formattedString
    }
}
```

And call this method like this for making a string in the middle as Bold

```
let descriptionText = "This is a bold string"
let descriptionText = descriptionText.attributedString(with: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .regular),
                                                              .foregroundColor: .black],
                                                    and: "bold",
                                                    with: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .bold),
                                                        .foregroundColor: .black])
```

Output: "This is a **bold** string". You can set this to UILabel as follows.

```
 textLabel.attributedString = descriptionText
```

This method can be used to highlight any range of text in the entire string with different styles, say bold, italics etc.
Please let me know if this helps.