# Inside a formatted string make a string bold

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have a string like this:

> Your score is %@.

I want the string to become :

> Your score is **perfect**.

I was thinking to use:

```
let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]
let boldAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "perfect".localized(), attributes: attrs)
String(format: "Your string is %@.", boldAttributedString)
```

I know my way around `NSMutableString` and attributed strings, but I'm not sure if it's possible because I have no way of doing a count of words, because in other languages it might be shorter or in a different order... The value for “perfect” is coming from an enum value.

Any ideas on how to approach this issue?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643869/ios-swift-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-specific-portion-of-text-bold/55644090#55644090

Comment: I would recommend using a 3rd party framework like [SwiftyAttributes](https://github.com/eddiekaiger/SwiftyAttributes), it'll make working with attributed strings in swift a lot easier.

Comment: There is not `NSAttributed(format:)` like `String(format:)`. The easiest way (and might be CPU consuming), would be to use HTML: `You string is <b>%@</b>`, do `let htmlString = String(format: "Your string is <b>%@.</b>", "perfect".localized())` and interpret it transforming it into NSAttributedString.

Comment: What I did in this scenario was I had to separate the strings since we support multiple languages, and as you said, are a different order for some. You can set the range something like: let range = (text as NSString).range(of: "perfect")
then: attributedString.addAttributes(attributedText, range: range). You can also use HTML tags to make this easier

Comment: @DavidA Only issue in your idea, is that there is that is doesn't work correctly with that kind of case: `"Your perfect string is %@."`. You'll detect the first "perfect".

Comment: @Larme ahh right, good catch :)

Comment: I really wish I had time to dig into this question right now; it's a great one, but I just popped on while waiting for a build to finish. Here's what you want to do: find or write a markup toolkit that lets you turn something like `Your score is <b>perfect</b>` into an attributed string. Localize `Your score is <b>%@</b>`, and then run that through the markup engine. I'd love to spend 20 minutes working out the details because this is a nice problem, but I can't right now, so comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSAttributedString` and ***append*** text and attributes:

```
    let normalAttrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
    let boldAttrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]

    let partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your score is ", attributes: normalAttrs)
    let partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "perfect".localized(), attributes: boldAttrs)
    let partThree = NSMutableAttributedString(string: ".", attributes: normalAttrs)

    partOne.append(partTwo)
    partOne.append(partThree)

    myLabel.attributedText = partOne
```

---

**Edit:**

Here's a more flexible approach using `NSMutableAttributedString`'s

```
replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, with attrString: NSAttributedString)
```

This will make it easy to replace `"%@"` in your localized string with a localized version of the "score word", regardless of length or position:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // simulate localized strings
        let localizedStrings = [
            "Your score is %@.",
            "You got a %@ score.",
            "%@ is your final score.",
            ]

        let localizedPerfects = [
            "Perfect",
            "Perfekt",
            "Perfectamente",
            ]

        let normalAttrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
        let boldAttrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]

        var y = 40

        for (scoreString, perfectString) in zip(localizedStrings, localizedPerfects) {

            // add a label
            let label = UILabel()
            view.addSubview(label)
            label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: y, width: 280, height: 40);
            y += 40

            if let rangeOfPctAt = scoreString.range(of: "%@") {

                let attStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: scoreString, attributes: normalAttrs)
                let attPerfect = NSAttributedString(string: perfectString, attributes: boldAttrs)

                let nsRange = NSRange(rangeOfPctAt, in: attStr.string)
                attStr.replaceCharacters(in: nsRange, with: attPerfect)

                label.attributedText = attStr

            } else {

                // "%@" was not in localized score string
                label.text = "invalid score string format"

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This won't work, just as the OP states, when localizing the format string and the `%@` isn't at the end.

Comment: @rmaddy - This suggestion avoids the use of `%@` to insert the localized "perfect".

Comment: But what if `"Your string is %@."` gets localized to `"Wotgy %@ htreye dfg."`? The OP brings this up in the question.

Comment: @rmaddy - In that case, the question is too vague: ***"I want to make part of a string bold, but I don't know what the string is or what word(s) I want to make bold."*** Presumably, the OP has determined his approach to localizing the string and will therefore know which "part(s)" should be normal and which "part(s)" should be bold.