# Issue splitting JSON response among tableview rows in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Currently I have the following JSON array:

```
[
    {
        "Time": "8:10 PM",
        "Person": "Jeff",
        "Place": "London"
    }
]
```

I would Time, Person, and Place values to each be split on individual cells.

Currently I have the following:

```
private func fetchJSON() {

    guard let url = URL(string: "\(URLValue)lookup.php"),
        let value = value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "value=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }


        do {

            self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([LookupStructure].self,from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()

}
```

With LookupStructure being the following:

```
struct LookupStructure: Decodable {

    let Time: String
    let Person: String
    let Place: String


    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case Time, Person, Place
    }

}
```

I am just having trouble understanding how I can display this JSON data on each row, meaning

`Time is on row 0, Person is on row 1 and Place is on row 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.structure.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // assuming you set up your kCellIdentifier somewhere
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: kCellIdentifier) ?? UITableViewCell()

        let `struct` = self.structure[indexPath.section]
        var textLabel: String? = nil

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            textLabel = `struct`.Time
            break
        case 1:
            textLabel = `struct`.Person
            break
        case 2:
            textLabel = `struct`.Place
            break
        default:
            fatalError("oopsies")
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = textLabel

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, if I add some text in front of the JSON data for each row, is there anyway to make only that text bold? Like: `textLabel = "Person: \(struct.Person)"`

Comment: Sure you can, basically do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586943/2057955