# UILabel with two different color text

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, nsattributedstring, textcolor

How can i have a `UILabel` with two different colors for the font? I will have text in two different strings and i want to make text with first string as **red** and second as **green**. The length of both the string is variable.

Comment: I had to do that too in a project. I used this class from another post but it's only for one **single** line, I don't know if it is enough for you. [iPhone - UILabel containing text with multiple fonts at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this within a `UILabel`s. But my suggestion is that instead of using multiple `UILabel` just concentrate on `NSAttributedString`. Find `UIControllers` that draw `NSAttributedString` because `UILabel`, `UITextView` do not support `NSAttributedString`.

*PS: if you plan to distribute an iOS6 or later application, as UILabel now support NSAttributedString, you should use UILabel directly instead of OHAttributedLabel as it is now natively supported by the OS.*

Comment: This answer is not correct any more because e.g. UILabel does support NSAttributedString since iOS 6.

Comment: @brainray I have updated the answer late year itself. Please check it.

Answer (score 8):

Try [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/). It's a subclass of UILabel that supports `NSAttributedString`s, which would make it easy to have multiple colors, fonts, and styles in the same string.

---

Edit: Alternatively, if you don't want the 3rd party dependency and are targeting iOS 6, `UILabel` now has the `attributedText` property.

Comment: Nice one. NSAttributedString is definitely the way to go - and the class you're suggesting seems very nice.

Answer (score 4):

UILabel can only have *one* color. You either need a more sophisticated element, or - probably easier - just use two separate labels. Use `[yourLabel sizeToFit];` and place them accordingly.

Comment: okkk i will try to explore sizeToFit property of uilabel, thanks for replying

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4** 

(*Note: notation for attributed string key is changed in swift 4*)

Here is an extension for `NSMutableAttributedString`, that add/set color on string/text.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setColor(color: UIColor, forText stringValue: String) {
        let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: stringValue, options: .caseInsensitive)
        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
    }

}
```

Now, try above extension with `UILabel` and see result

```
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 280, height: 200)
let red = "red"
let blue = "blue"
let green = "green"
let stringValue = "\(red)\n\(blue)\n&\n\(green)"
label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
label.numberOfLines = 0
let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
attributedString.setColor(color: UIColor.red, forText: red)   // or use direct value for text "red"
attributedString.setColor(color: UIColor.blue, forText: blue)   // or use direct value for text "blue"
attributedString.setColor(color: UIColor.green, forText: green)   // or use direct value for text "green"
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26)
label.attributedText = attributedString
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Here is solution in **Swift 3**:

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
        func setColorForText(textToFind: String, withColor color: UIColor) {
         let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind, options: .caseInsensitive)
          if range != nil {
            self.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: range)
          }
        }

}


func multicolorTextLabel() {
        var string: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "red\nblue\n&\ngreen")
        string.setColorForText(textToFind: "red", withColor: UIColor.red)
        string.setColorForText(textToFind: "blue", withColor: UIColor.blue)
        string.setColorForText(textToFind: "green", withColor: UIColor.green)
        labelObject.attributedText = string
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Just tried this in iOS 11 and got an error in the extension.. self.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color], range: range)

Comment: @August - Please share error message. Also let me know swift version of your project. You may be trying with Swift 3 extension and your project has Swift 4. Please share error related info, so I can help you.

Comment: Yes, it is a Swift 4 project and used the Swift 4 extension you shared. It was a syntax error, not a compile/runtime error. Doc » https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1414304-addattributes

Comment: ...and sorry for the vague comment, I posted it and forgot to make sure it actually worked. As a result, it took a bit longer than the 5 minute edit time limit. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 UILabel has NSAttributedString property. So use that.