# Is it possible to to have more than one color in the same UILabel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I want more than one font color in the same UILabel. I dont know if it is possible. I dont really think so but maybe some of you out there have a smart solution for it? Maybe something like `stringWithFormat`. `[NSString stringWithFormatAndColor: @"Text with color: %@ %@", text, color, text, color]`

This image illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952571/uilabel-with-two-different-color-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with NSAttributedSting. An easy to use drop-in replacement for UILabels with support for attributed strings is [TTTAtributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) or [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

In my experience it is easier to work with NSMutableAttributedStrings and build it up step by step.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@""];

NSMutableAttributedString *a = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"This is "];      
[a setTextColor:aColorObj];
NSMutableAttributedString *b = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"only one "];     
[b setTextColor:bColorObj];
NSMutableAttributedString *c = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"Label"];     
[c setTextColor:cColorObj];

[attrStr appendAttributedString:a];
[attrStr appendAttributedString:b];
[attrStr appendAttributedString:c];


OHAttributedLabel *attributedTextLabel = [[OHAttributedLabel] initWithFrame:frame]
[attributedTextLabel setAttributedText:attrStr];
```

Comment: Note that Viking's solution will only work for Mac OS. iOS doesn't support mixed text styles in UIKit objects. You have to either use a web view or drop down to Core Text to display multiple styles in the same string. You can also fake it by putting separate labels next to each other.

Comment: I tried the code above and it does work. @DuncanC did you take into account that we are using a OHAttributedLabel and not a UILabel?