# How to create a bold and normal font text in single UILabel in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I want to create like following Sample text in UILabel..

> **Muthu:** Hi I am on the way to office..
>              wait for the few mins...

This type of text have UITableviewCustom cell have the  UILabel.

How to create in the UILabel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code and include the .h and .m files from the following link "https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel".

```
-(void)addTitleView{

    NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"Muthu: Hi I am on the way to office..wait for the few mins..."];
    [attrStr setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:16]];
    [attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [attrStr setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:16] range:NSMakeRange(0,6)];
    
    OHAttributedLabel *titleLabel = [[OHAttributedLabel alloc] init];
    titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 35)];
    [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    titleLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentJustify;
    [self.view addSubview:titleLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UILabels with support for attributed strings is [TTTAtributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) or [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

I use OHAttributedLabel. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789518/is-it-possible-to-to-have-more-than-one-color-in-the-same-uilabel) ansewr for an example and use setTextBold for boldness.

Answer (score 0):

You got to use [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There are many open source components available to do that for you. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring).