# Unicode characters display in UILabel

Tags: iphone, unicode, uilabel, iso

Display unicode characters in a UILabel as follows:

```
NSString *str = @"flag \u2691 and heart \u2764";
myUILabel.text = str;
```

The flag is displayed in black and white, while the heart is displayed in red with gradual change. So the question is: is it possible to control the color of unicode characters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952571/uilabel-with-two-different-color-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/). It allows you to style your text label with more than 1 color. (Also lets you have different fonts in one label)

Comment: Yes, I know this class, but I wander if it could implemented with UILabel. Thx for your reply:)

Comment: It's not possible to use have more than one color with UILabel unfortunately

Comment: maybe it's possible with unicode characters, such as the heart displayed in red with gradual change.

Comment: Thanks for mentionning my OHAttributedLabel class ;) And no these colored characters are emoji glyphs so are a very special case (the color is included in Apple's glyph representation of this special emoji character)