# UILabel text as html text

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4

I am stuck with a small issue.

I need to use a sentence which will have first two words bold and last two words italic. Like:

> I **am using** an O*bjective C* Developer.

How to do that. Is this possible in Objective C?

Comment: can't you add two `UIlabel`? if so, first one with bold style and the other one with italic style.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For iOS7 you can use this:

```
NSString * htmlString = @"<html><body> Some html string </body></html>";
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

UILabel * myLabel = [UILabel alloc] init];
myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Answer (score 3):

Apple recommends that for small amounts of styled text, you should use a web view, and display the text marked up in HTML and formatted with CSS, etc.

Personally I've never taken that advice, as I would consider a UI full of web views to be a bit over kill.

There is the Core Text framework, if you want a little more control over your text and want to use attributed strings.

It isn't a one-liner though. Using core text requires quite a lot of code.

I have written a core text view that will display tappable URL links inline with text, but I have not given it arbitrary formatting support. If you're interested in showing links within text, then check it out: https://github.com/jasarien/CoreTextHyperlinkView

You may be interested in Oliver Drobnik's rich text view, which is based on Core Text too. As far as I know, you can feed it HTML and it'll produce a native view containing your formatted text. Very useful. It can be found here: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText

Comment: Thanks Jasarien.I am trying this out.

Comment: The link for Oliver Drobnik's rich text view is broken!

Answer (score 2):

I've written a very small class called **THMultiPartLabel** to help me accomplish this sort of thing - you can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/tomheinan/THMultiPartLabel).  It's based heavily on Jason's answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time/1532634#1532634).  Using this class, you'd implement your example like so:

```
UIFont *normal = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
UIFont *bold = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
UIFont *italic = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:20];

NSArray *fonts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: normal, bold, normal, italic, normal nil];
THMultiPartLabel *mpLabel = [[THMultiPartLabel alloc] initWithOffsetX:0 Y:0 defaultFonts:fonts];

[mpLabel updateText:@"I ", @"am using ", @"an ", @"Objective C ", "Developer", nil];
```

Comment: How do you expect people to use this for longer texts? A solution should be generic in nature that can cater to a larger text but at the same time should be easier to use. I am not giving a thumbs down for this answer since we should do so only if this does not answer the query but this is in no way a acceptable solution. Sorry for that but thats my opinion

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at Core Text.

Here are some useful resources:

- [Befriending Core Text](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) on Cocoanetics.com
- [Core Text Reference Collection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_Framework_Ref/_index.html) - official Apple documentation
- [SimpleTextInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleTextInput/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010633) - Example app by Apple
- [CoreTextPageViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTextPageViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010699) - Example app by Apple

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to replace the UILabel with a UIWebView and use HTML to do the formatting.

[EDIT]

If you have lots of them and think there is too much of a performance hit, you can (from iOS 3.2 onwards) also consider [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributedString), although that will be a lot more coding.

Comment: Oi, don't use a `UIWebView` for something that small.  The `UIWebView` is a very expensive object.  Depending on his requirements, he's better off creating separate labels or creating a static image.  There are no clear choices here, mostly because the use case isn't really specified, but I would not use a `UIWebView` for this.

Comment: For a lot of (simple) cases there is no noticeable performance hit with the UIWebView but I agree it's not necessarily the right solution without knowing more about the use case.

Comment: Thanks Roger, actually I would like to go with CoreText. Seems convincing to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do both with the standard UILabel implementation. But you can do one or the other.

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:18];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 6 you can use NSAttributedString with an UILabel, a NSAttributedString takes a NSString as an argument in one of its contructors, after that you can specify which ranges of this string has a particular text style.

You can find a good example on how to do it on iOS 6 here: http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/31931916393/introduction-to-nsattributedstring-for-ios-6

If you what something backwards compatible, I'm strongly recommend the OHAttributedLabel which can be found here: https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

Note: OHAttributedLabel also allows the usage of html markup to style your label text.