# iPhone: UILabel of variable length, multi-line strings with multiple fonts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fonts, uilabel

I would like to do something like this on the iPhone with a UILabel:

**John Doe, Jane Doe, John Smith,

Jane Smith** like this photo.

I could draw my own text and have it implement multiple fonts on the same line, like in the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time), but once it spans multiple lines, that sort of solution doesn't really seem to work because the `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` method returns a `CGRect`, and I'd imagine it either to make something like this:

**John Doe, Jane Doe, John Smith, Jane Smith** like this photo.

Or like this:

**John Doe, Jane Doe, John Smith,

Jane Smith** 
like this photo.

But I'd like to continue the 2nd font right where the 1st font left off and on the same line. Is there any way to make this happen on the iPhone?

Comment: If using three20 library is an option, then you can make use of the [three20](http://www.three20.info) TTStyledText's textFromXHTML function. Example usage can be found in the TTCatalog project. Here is the documentation of the [TTStyledText](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_styled_text.php)

Comment: It could be more useful to you the **UITextView object** (setting it as **not editable**, you will obtain from it a behavior pretty close to the UILabel, with more flexibility).

Answer (score 1):

I have used Core Text to handle texts like these to display different fonts at certain places. Core Text gives you a lot of flexibility in terms of changing font, size and setting paragraph attributes. More information about Core text can be found here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html

To give you an example of how it is done:

```
-(void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layerToDraw inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
NSMutableAttributedString* someString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"New String"];
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(@"Arial", 25, NULL);
[someString addAttribute:(id)kCTFontAttributeName value:(id)font range:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
CFRelease(font);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, labelLayer.bounds);

CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, labelLayer.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(someString);
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);

CTFrameDraw(frame, context);


CFRelease(framesetter);
CFRelease(frame);
CFRelease(path);
}
```

But if such usage is very less in your project, you can just use UIWebView to show such text (remember that this consumes more resources)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to set different / multiple fonts & other properties on Label using NSMutableAttributedString. Foll is my code:

```
 UIFont *ArialFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:18.0];
 NSDictionary *arialdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: ArialFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];    
 NSMutableAttributedString *AattrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes: arialdict];

 UIFont *VerdanaFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:12.0];
 NSDictionary *veradnadict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:VerdanaFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
 NSMutableAttributedString *VattrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString: newsDate attributes:veradnadict];    
 [VattrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:(NSMakeRange(0, 15))];

 [AattrString appendAttributedString:VattrString];


 lblText.attributedText = AattrString;
```

Note that lblText is the UILabel, outlet as file owner.
One can keep on appending as many NSMutableAttributedString he wants..

Also Note that I've added verdana & arial font in my project & added a plist for the same.