# Have half a UILabel text bold and half not?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, text-formatting

I want half of my `UILabel`'s `text` to be bold and half to not be bold. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) allows for specification of formatting within a string, but sadly, UIKit does not yet do anything with this. However, there are a few open-source implementations that do. Check out [OHAttributedLabel](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ohattributedlabel).

Comment: OHAttributedLabel has not maintaining anymore by the creator.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this easily unless you subclass UILabel and mess with the subviews.  Better to use two UILabels instead.  Found [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time) about it here.

Answer (score 0):

UILabel has `attributedText` which takes a `NSAttributedString` which allows you to customize multiple aspects of a string including changing the font type and other attributes

```
  var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(string: "Not Bold"))

  let boldAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: "BOLD", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 15)!])
  attributedString.appendAttributedString(boldAttrString)
  myLabel.attributesText = attributedString
```