# How can I bold some text in the UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel

For example, I would like to display something like this:

`It is my`**bold**`text label.`

But `It is my`'s length cannot be expected, because, it may become

`Oh! It is my` **bold** `text label.`

So, I can't use 3 labels to do so. Any recommends? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have half a UILabel text bold and half not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180805/have-half-a-uilabel-text-bold-and-half-not)

Comment: @Thilo It might seem a dupe at first glance but I'm not convinced it is; the popularly accepted answer to this question is that, without 3rd party classes, the only way to do it is with multiple labels.  Unlike the question you linked and some others, Ted's question displays a prior understanding of this; he knows multiple labels are the common answer, but doesn't think they'll work in his case.  (Not true, as I've shown below).  But IMO it's not quite a dupe because of this distinction. (Though of course we can agree to disagree ^^)

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UILabel cannot do this out of the box.

I recommend using [OHAttributedLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869071/14955), which is available on [github](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel).

Comment: OHAttributedLabel is not maintaining by the creator anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can still use 3 labels :)

Assuming the `It is my` label is `label1`, write a wrapper function that you always call to change `label1`'s text; this function should also recalculate `label1`'s size and reposition `label2` and `label3`.

```
-(void) setLabel1Text(NSString* newText)
{
    label1.text = newText;
    int label1TextLength = [label1.text sizeWithFont:label1.font];

    label2.x = label1.x + label1TextLength;
    label3.x = label2.x + label2.width;
}
```

And voila :)

Comment: works, but rather inflexible if you suddenly need more than three ranges. NSAttributedString-based solutions are better IMHO. Hopefully iOS 6 will have better support for it.

Answer (score -1):

Using a 'UILabel', this is not strictly possible.  You can use bold fonts, however, if you want all text to be bold.  Reference thi[this page](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/) for a list of fonts.  For example, instead of Helvetica, you can use Helvetica-Bold.  With plain `UILabel`s, however, formatting is all or nothing; all the text has to be bold, or none of it is bold.  To display rich text with some parts bold, other parts not, however, check out `NSMutableAttributedString`.
Good luck!