# Different font in one Label

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am using one label in navigation bar item.In that label two types of font are there.Suppose 
label.text = @"Topics";

In this "T" is having font Georgia and "opics" is having the font Arial.

How I will do this?

I tried with self.navigationItem.titleView but it is taking all font same type,
I tried with two string with different font and append those two.But that also didn't work.
Please help.

Comment: Check the following SO Link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4183643/433794)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straightforward way..

1) Use two UILabels, each with a different font.. Move the second one over the first based on where the first one's text ends. You can use sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode: to size of one text

2)Other option, you subclass UILabel, draw text in drawRect:, Use any logic to differentiate between 2 strings in different fonts

3) There is a third possibility..But since I never tried it, I can't give much information..May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel) question might be of help..

**EDIT** : In iOS 6 UILabel, UITextView and other similar classes support NSAttributedString which can be used to have different font types/styles in single label text. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel/3586943#3586943) answer clearly explains it. So no need to add it here.

Comment: Is there any example about moving second one over the first based on where the first one's text end?

Answer (score 0):

Your not going to be able to use 2 different fonts on 1 label.

I would suggest using 2 labels aligned properly to get the "1 label" look, then you can set the font for each label.

Comment: I understand that this was correct when it was written, but it's not correct now. ;]