# UILabel text Issue in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I have one label which have a Dynamic string data e.g: "I am Mohit" .I want to make only "am" in bold.Is it Possible in iphone? if yes please give me suggestion.Thanks in advance:)

Comment: try this link : http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/rtlabel

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - UILabel containing text with multiple fonts at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time)

Comment: try this Thread,...i hope you got ur answer..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't have text with different styles in standard UILabel. What you'll probably need to use is `NSAttributedString` and some custom solution to display them. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring) for some possible options.

Answer (score 1):

Not with `UILabel`. Suggest 2 labels, or subclass. Many related answers, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't have text with different styles in standard UILabel. 
You need to use  NSAttributedString and some custom solution to display them. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring)

Answer (score 0):

done something like this using [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20)'s TTStyledTextLabel :) it works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

you can use textView instead of label to fulfill your requirement.

ex:-

[textview setContentToHTMLString:@""];

Comment: This method is now deprecated. If you use this method in your app then apple will reject your app.