# Formatted text in UILabel on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, uilabel

Our requirement is to show some text bold and some text as normal style in a label.

e.g. **ABC** 002
(there is not space between ABC and 002)

There are lots of instances of such labels on a single view, so using UIWebView is not preferred.

Is it possible using the UILabel? If no, then what are the alternatives?

Comment: you have to use two diffrent labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using normal `UILabel` dont think this is possible.

Check out this replacement for UILabel [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).

Another way is to use a [CATextLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time) with an NSAttributedString ! much lighter and simpler than 2 UILabels. (iOS 3.2 and above) as suggested here - [Bold & Non-Bold Text In A Single UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel)

Another way is to use 2 `UILabels` and position them correctly relative to each other Check out [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time) from a previous Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ramesh what did u end up doing ? which of my above solutions are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

For making the such labels you might have to use TTStyledTextLabel of Three20 libraries, which allows different styles on the same object of text.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that requirement using TTStyledTextLabel of [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) library