# Convert NSString to HTML and set HTML text into UILabel

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

Is it possible to convert a NSString to html and set as a label?

The code below shows the NSString I want to set finalPrice as bold text and finalStr&shipping string as normal text

```
NSString *myText = [NSString 
     stringWithFormat:
       @"%@\nFinal price including $%.2f Shipping and all discount: <b>$%.2f</b>",
      finalStr,shipping,finalPrice];
lbl.text = myText;
```

I want to set multiple color and multiple text type into same dyanamic label.

Comment: So basically you need a special formatting, not exactly an html, right?

Comment: @FreeNickname : i need conversion for another string which i not specify in question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't tell you an exact solution, but this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696097/formatted-text-in-uilabel-on-iphone

Comment: @FreeNickname : But my label is dynamic and i want to set multiple color and multiple text into same label so please help me.

Comment: Use [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776741/how-to-create-a-uilabel-or-uitextview-with-bold-and-normal-text-in-it)

Comment: @HAS : it's not helpful for me because i have only one label and i want to use all label property.

Comment: I think I don't understand what you want. If you have one label and want to display formatted text (bold, italic, color, etc) that's exactly the case where you should use `NSAttributedString`. What do you mean by `I want to use all label property`? Which ones can't you use using `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: you can't use different font and different colours in a single `UILabel`. Try using just a simple `UIView` or a `UIWebView`

Comment: @Novarg Of course you can, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following label for bold effects. Or you can get code from that class.

[DAAttributedStringUtils](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/daattributedstringutils)

and also see this

[Different Label](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=uilabel)

**Edit**

```
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nFinal price including $%.2f Shipping and all discount: %%B$%.2f%%b",finalStr,shipping,finalPrice];


     DAAttributedLabel* lbl = [[DAAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 30.0f, 260.0f, 24.0f)];
     lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9f green:0.9f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f]; 
     lbl.text = (id)[formatter formatString:myText];
     [self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

Comment: DAAttributedLabel *label1;
But i can't set it like this lbl.text = label1;

Comment: see my updated answer, no need use your lbl.

Comment: but how can i set your label dyanamic?????

Comment: How can i set all label property like numberOfLines etc.?

Comment: see this method [lbl setPreferredHeight]; you can set height no need to set numberoflines.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

There are already several questions around this here like
[How do you use NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring)

```
NSString * textString = @"Hello Bold";
NSInteger _stringLength = [textString length];
NSMutableAttributedString * attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textString];

[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f]; range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];

[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0f]; range:NSMakeRange(6, 4)];

myLabel.attributedText = attString;
```

(code not tested)

Edit:
label.attributedText is only available for iOS 6.0+

Comment: @joao : Here my string len is not fix.

Comment: You can calc string sizes on the fly. If you problem is the "numbers" NSString * priceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", 123.1234566]; NSInteger priceLength = [priceString length]; @HAS actually posted the full code for your case

Comment: I forgot to say that label.attributedText is only for 6.0+

Comment: But with [these statistics](http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/) you can neglect this IMHO ;)

Comment: @joao : App crashed it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the answer above suggesting the use of DAAttributedStringUtils and DAAttributedLabel didn't mention that these are convenience classes for the use of NSAttributedString.  They make formatting NSAttributedString instances a little easier.  As an example, here's how to do the same formatting described about by HAS using DAAttributedStringUtils:

```
float finalPrice = 34.99, shipping = 4.99;

// Setup the formatter
DAAttributedStringFormatter* formatter = [[DAAttributedStringFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.defaultFontFamily = @"Georgia";
formatter.defaultFontSize = 12.0f;
formatter.colors = @[ [UIColor blackColor], [UIColor redColor] ];
NSAttributedString* attrStr = [formatter formatString:@"%0C%0FRed Courier Text %1C%1FBlue Arial Text %0CRed Arial Text"];

// setup base strings
NSString *finalStr = @"Some Text. ";
NSString *shippingAttributed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%B%%1C$%.2f%%b%%c", shipping];
NSString *middleText0 = @"Final price including ";
NSString *middleText1 = @" Shipping and all discount: ";
NSString *finalPriceAttributed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%B%%1C$%.2f%%b%%c", finalPrice];

// Format the strings
self.label.attributedText = [formatter formatString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%%B%%1C%@%%b%%c%@%%B%%1C%@", finalStr, shippingAttributed, middleText0, middleText1, finalPriceAttributed];
```

Somewhat less code, and I think easier to understand.  FYI, the formatter string in the last line contains codes that are used to modify the format of portions of the string.  Those codes use double percents (