# Change text size in different lines of textlabel cell uitableview

Tags: uitableview, textlabel

I created a uitableview and in every cell there's a textLabel.

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello\n how are you?"];
UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Novel" size: 6.0 ];
cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;
```

Can i set the font of "Hello" to 10 and the font of "how are you?" to 6?

Thank you!

Comment: possible dup of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time

Answer (score -1):

Do as per the following:

```
UILabel *flabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
flabel.text = @"Hello";
flabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:flabel.text size:10];
UILabel *slabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
slabel.text = @"How are you?";
slabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:slabel.text size:6];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",flabel.text,slabel.text];
```

I have created two different labels having different font size and set it to cell textlabel by concatenation of both strings.
Hope this should work.

Comment: Thank you but It doesn't work... I think that : cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",flabel.text,slabel.text]; it sets only the text of the flabel and slabel and not the font and size prefrences