# Append UILabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview

I am developing iPhone app, in which i got stuck at one point,

what i want to do is, i have `UITableView` and in the UITableViewCell i want to display the text like this:

India in **Country23**
Australia in **Country2**
USA in **Country22**
AMERI in **Country26**
FRANCE in **Country12**
ITALY in **Country20**
WEST INDIES in **Country42**
KENYA
SOUTH AFRICA
NEW ZEALAND

The text before `in` is in one array and text after `in` (which is in BOLD) is in another array and also i want to change the text color of BOLD text which is after `in`

**Note:** Some of the cell contains bold text and some doesn't

How to display data like this in `UITableVIew` ?

**please help and thanks in advance.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - UILabel containing text with multiple fonts at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time)

Comment: are you using single uilabel for show that data in cell

Comment: @Rohit: yes `Cell.textlabel.text= @"---";`

Comment: Better option will be to take two `UILabel`. In that case it will be easy to play with them.

Comment: In two `UILabel` how to decide frame of second `UILabel` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to bold part of a NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013705/any-way-to-bold-part-of-a-nsstring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example

```
@implementation MyTableViewController
{
    NSArray *_countryNames;
    NSArray *_countryNumbers;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _countryNames = @[@"India", @"Australia", @"USA"];
    _countryNumbers = @[@"Country23", @"Country2", @"Country22"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return MIN(_countryNames.count, _countryNumbers.count);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"reuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: identifier];
    }
    NSString *text1 = _countryNames[indexPath.row];
    NSString *text2 = _countryNumbers[indexPath.row];
    NSString *completeText = [[text1 stringByAppendingString:@" " ] stringByAppendingString:text2];

    const CGFloat fontSize = 13;
    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    UIFont *regularFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];

    NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSFontAttributeName : regularFont};

    NSDictionary *subAttrs = @{NSFontAttributeName : boldFont};
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(text1.length + 1, text2.length);

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:completeText
                                           attributes:attrs];
    [attributedText setAttributes:subAttrs range:range];

    [cell.textLabel setAttributedText:attributedText];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: @Krunal `NSDictionary *subAttrs = @{NSFontAttributeName : boldFont,
                               NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]};` Just add another key to the sub-attributes dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use custom uilabel with NSAttributedString or an NSMutableAttributedString functionality like this example

```
NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];
    NSString *yourString = ...;
    NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(22, 4);

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

    [attrString beginEditing];
    [attrString addAttribute:kCTFontAttributeName 
                       value:boldFontName
                       range:boldedRange];

    [attrString endEditing];

  [_label setAttributedText:attrString];
```