# Multiple font sizes in a single UITableview cell (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, font-size

I have a UITableviewCell with multiple lines of text. I am trying to figure out how to make each line a different font size.

Here is the code I am using to populate the table cell:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventCell")!
        cell.textLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

        cell.textLabel!.text = self.eventsToday[indexPath.row].eventTitle + "\n" + self.eventsToday[indexPath.row].eventPlaceName

        return cell
    }
```

Is there a way to reduce the font size after the "\n" line break so that the string labeled "eventPlaceName" will show up as smaller than the one labeled "eventTitle?"

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time

Comment: you can use attributed string for attributed string example you can see at below [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Use `attributedText` property of `textLabel` object.

Using `attributedText` you can format your text.

For more, see [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc%28cs%29NSAttributedString)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to reduce the font size after the "\n" line break so
>   that the string labeled "eventPlaceName" will show up as smaller than
>   the one labeled "eventTitle?"

This sounds exactly like your table view cell needs **TWO SEPARATE labels:**

1. One for the "Event title"
2. One for the "Event place"

I mean, you *could* use an attributed string, but clearly these are two separate pieces of information and you have a repeating pattern here. Two labels sounds like the best practice / less headaches down the road, in my opinion.

---

**How to add an extra label:**

1. Subclass `UITableViewCell` (Let's call the custom subclass `CustomTableCell` in the code below).
2. Set the class of your prototype cells to your custom subclass, in the storyboard. **Also set the reuse identifier** (here I used "YourCellIdentifier").
3. Forget the original label (it doesn't show in the storyboard and therefore you couldn't position your second label relative to it); instead add **TWO** new labels to the cell, and setup outlets with the custom cell subclass. Name the properties (e.g.) `eventTitleLabel` and `eventPlaceLabel`. Setup any layout constraints you may need, and configure the font sizes, colors, etc.
4. At runtime, set the labels' text like so:

   ```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableCell
   // (forced cast shouldn't fail f identifier is registered properly)

   cell.eventTitleLabel.text = "Event Title XXXX"
   cell.eventPlaceLabel.text = "Event Place YYYY"

   return cell
   ```

Comment: This looks like it may be the most convenient solution. One question though - how to I create a new label in the cell? Should I make it in the main storyboard and then connect it to the View Controller or is there a line of code that will work for this?

Comment: See my edited answer for details on how to achieve that.