# How can I set different font size between letter and number in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make the letter font size bigger and number font size smaller in UILabel's text. How can I do?

I tried to use NSAttributedString, but it seems to receive a confirmed range to change. This can not meet my needs。

Thanks a lot

Comment: Since that's likely what you'll need to do, maybe you can write an algorithm that *meet your needs*. Update the various ranges as needed based on their contents?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with `NSAttributedString`?

This is a `String` extension returning an attributed string. You can pass the font size for letter and digit.

It uses Regular Expression to find the numeric ranges

```
extension String {

    func attributedString(letterSize: CGFloat, digitSize: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString
    {
        let pattern = "\\d+"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        let matches = regex.matches(in: self, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.count))
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self, attributes: [.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: letterSize)])
        matches.forEach { attributedString.addAttributes([.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: digitSize)], range: $0.range) }
        return attributedString.copy() as! NSAttributedString
    }
}
```

And use it

```
let string = """
Apple Computer Inc.
1 Infinite Loop Cupertino
CA 95014
(800) 275-2273
"""

let attributedString = string.attributedString(letterSize: 14.0, digitSize: 18.0)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In that case you could use a regular expression to get ranges of numbers to retrieve their ranges and set their attributes accordingly.